# How do I store a variable length string in C/C++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to slurp a file into a std::string in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c)

Im trying to store a whole text file as a string, 
how can I dynamically store any amount of characters the text file may contain?

Comment: What's the size of your file like? 20GB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to slurp a file into a std::string in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c) or [What is the most elegant way to read a text file with c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195323/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-read-a-text-file-with-c)

Comment: @KingsIndian, Nothing more than a few kilobytes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C++ Standard Library provides the `std::string` type for dynamically sized strings. It is a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`. There's [a useful reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) at cppreference.com.

For reading lines from a file into a `std::string`, take a look at [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). You can use it to get a line from a file as follows:

```
std::string str;
std::getline(file_stream, str);
```

Be sure to check the stream (it is returned by `std::getline`) to see if everything went okay. This is often done in a loop:

```
while (std::getline(file_stream, str)) {
  // Use str
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to sftrabbit's answer:

Note that you can read a whole file into a string in one go by doing this:

```
std::ifstream input_ifstr(filename.c_str());

std::string str(
    (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(input_ifstr)),
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

input_ifstr.close();
```

You can construct a stringstream from it to process with getline afterwards if you wish.