# Reading variable size 2D-STL vector from file

Tags: c++

```
2 
1 3 
2 4 8 13
3 5 6 13
4
4
8
3 7 9 10 13 
8 10 11 
8 9 11 12 
9 10 
10 15 
3 4 8 14 
13 
12 16 
15 17 18 
16 
18 16
```

I want to read this these values from file into two dimensional STL vector. Note that the size of inner vector is not uniform and not known in adance so I need to detect '\n'. So far I have been unnsuccessful. My code is as follows. Please help. What is wrong?

```
int main()
{
    ifstream Lin("A.txt");
    double d;
    vector<vector<double> > A;
    vector<double> dummy;

    if (Lin.is_open()){
    while (Lin >> d) {
            if (Lin.peek() == '\n'){
                A.push_back(dummy);
                dummy.clear();
            }else{
                dummy.push_back(d);
            } 
        }
        Lin.close();
    }

...

return 0;

}
```

When I iterate over the vector using the following code
 , it reveals what is stored:

```
for(int i = 0; i< A.size(); i++){
       for(int j = 0; j< A[i].size() ; j++){
           cout << A[i][j] << " ";
       }
       cout << endl;
   }


1
2 4 8
3 5 6



3 7 9 10
8 10
8 9 11
9
10
3 4 8

12
15 17

18
```

The intended output is same as the way it is stored in the file

Comment: "I have been unnsuccessful" is not detailed enough. Please be precise about what happens and what you expect.

Comment: You may wish to check out `getline` and `stringstream`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that there is no empty space after the last integer in each line in the data file.
In the code currently you are not adding the last integer to the dummy vector. Modify it like this:

```
while (Lin >> d) 
{
       dummy.push_back(d);   // Add the number first
       if (Lin.peek() == '\n')  // Then check if it is end of line
       {
             A.push_back(dummy);
             dummy.clear();
       }
}
```

Comment: @UtkristAdhikari: Apart from saying thank you, upvoting this answer will be _nicer_ :)

Answer (score 2):

Consider using getline.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > v;
    while(std::getline(cin, line)) {
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        double value;
        std::vector<double> numbers;
        while(ss >> value) {
            numbers.push_back(value);
            std::cout << value << std::endl;
        }
        v.push_back(numbers);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Will the numbers be stored as appropriate datatype inside the vector. I am asking this since we are reading the line into string.

Answer (score 2):

Less is more. This replaces your entire loop. Note: You *don't* need to check `is_open` or call `close` for this to work safely.

```
for(std::string s; std::getline(Lin, s);)
{
    A.emplace_back(std::istream_iterator<double>(std::istringstream(s)), 
                   std::istream_iterator<double>());
}
```

Comment: needs extra set of parentheses http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195323/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-read-a-text-file-with-c

Comment: for me this doesn't work. I have to convert `string` to `stringstream` in a separate line. gcc 4.8.0

Answer (score 0):

There could be other whitespace characters after the number at the end of line, other than `\n`. Like spaces:

```
1234  445  445    \n
              ^^^^
```

So your approach is not safe. Better would be to read entire line (`getline`) to some string, then construct `istringstream` on this `string` containing line, then just parse this `istringstream` to your `vector` for one line.

Like this:

```
   for (string line; getline(filein, line); ) {
        vector<double> dd;
        istringstream is(line);
        for (double d; is >> d; )
            dd.push_back(d);
        if (not dd.empty())
           A.push_back(dd);
    }
```