# How can I get the real size of a file with C++?

Tags: c++, file, size, byte

I'm using `tellg()` to get the size of some files, and it's very important for this project get the real/correct size of files. Now I'm bit worried because a read that tellg() doesn't work perfectly but it can get the wrong size, maybe bigger than the real size. For example here: [tellg() function give wrong size of file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984956/tellg-function-give-wrong-size-of-file)

How can I get the correct size?? or isn't it true that `tellg` does'nt work very well?

This is my code with `tellg()`:

```
streampos begin,end;
    ifstream file_if(cpd_file, ios::binary);
    begin = file_if.tellg();
    file_if.seekg(0, ios::end);
    end = file_if.tellg();
    file_if.close();
    size = end - begin;
```

Comment: On some operating systems (notably Linux) *another* process could modify an opened file, so the question might not make any sense (in other words, the retrieved size would always be approximate).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ok, but I don't think it is that the problem that I find in the linked question above.. no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get file's size and other info like it's creation and modification time, it's owner, permissions etc. you can use the `stat()` function.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct stat s;
if (stat("path/to/file.txt", &s)) {
    // error
}

printf("filesize in bytes: %u\n", s.st_size);
```

Documentation:

- Linux version: [stat(2)](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)
- Windows version: [_stat, _stat32, _stat64, _stati64, _stat32i64, _stat64i32, _wstat, _wstat32, _wstat64, _wstati64, _wstat32i64, _wstat64i32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

At this moment, you can use [boost::filesystem::file_size](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#file_size) to get the file size.

In the near future, it will be standardized to `std::filesystem::file_size`, it's an experimental feature, see [std::experimental::filesystem::file_size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/file_size).

[std::experimental::filesystem::file_size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/file_size) is supported by:

- MSVC 2013 or later,
- `libstdc++` 5.3 or later
- `libc++` 3.8 or later