# How to portably obtain the offset in bytes from the beginning of an istream?

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, portability

We are reading into a file by accessing it through a `std::ifstream`, let's call it `ifs`.
In our current procedure, we make a few formatted input operations (i.e. using `operator>>()`), which leads us to a given position in the stream, let's call it `posA`

Then, want to re-read from the beginning of the file until `posA` in a `char` buffer. To achieve this, we make an unformatted input opeation (using `read()`).

### Our naïve approach

What we were doing under Unix OSes was to initialize `posA` with the value from `tellg()`, then convert use it as the integral value offset from the beginning of the file:

(simplified code)

```
// several formatted input operations
std::istream::pos_type posA = ifs.tellg(); 
ifs.seekg(0); // rewind to the beginning of the stream
ifs.read(buffer, posA);
```

Sadly, when porting the code we discovered that the `pos_type` returned by `tellg()` is not necessarily the byte offset from the beginning of the stream (see also [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22986486/1027706)).

### The question

Which leads us to the question: is there a portable way to get the current position in an input stream (or at least an `std::ifstream`) as the number of bytes from the beginning of the stream/file  ? (So this value could notably be used to `read()` the bytes from the beginning until this exact position).

Answer (score 0):

The only resort is to open the file in binary mode, e.g. `std::ifstream f{filename, std::ios_base::binary};`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Is it guaranteed by the standard that opening it in binary mode, the integral return value of ``tellg()`` has to be the byte offset from the beginning of the file ? (the SO link in my questions seems to imply that it is not necessarily the case out of Unices and Windows).

Comment: @AdN The C++ standard does not require that.

Comment: So this is sadly not a portable approach

Comment: @AdN No other approach with IOStreams.