# ifstream::seekg giving wrong results

Tags: c++, ifstream, seekg

I am playing with ifstream to familiarize myself with it. I am trying to use seekg to tell the position of the file, but it is giving me wrong results.

The idea is to:

1. open the file
2. print position of the file
3. read a character from the file
4. print position of the file
5. read a character from the file
6. print position of the file
7. close the file.

The original file looks like this(windows format):

**file.txt**

```
aA
bB
cC
dD
eE
fF
```

running my code, I get the results:

```
position: 0
got: a
position: 6
got: A
position: 7
```

However, for this file:

**file.txt**

```
aAbBcCdDeEfF
```

I get these results

```
position: 0
got: a
position: 1
got: A
position: 2
```

Here is the code I used:

**test.cpp**(mingw/gcc5.3)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static char s[10];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ifstream f("file.txt");    
    cout << "position: " << f.tellg() << "\n";
    f.read(s, 1);
    cout << "got: " << s << "\n";
    cout << "position: " << f.tellg() << "\n";
    f.read(s, 1);
    cout << "got: " << s << "\n";
    cout << "position: " << f.tellg() << "\n";    
    f.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Here are the two hex editor views of the two text files respectively:

**original**: [image]
**modified**: [image]

I expected both to yield the results 0, 1, 2 respectively, however this was not the case for the original experiment.

Can somebody explain what is happening here?

**Questions**:

1. What should I do to get the correct file position?

> Answer: use `ifstream("file.txt", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary)` constructor over `ifstream("file.txt")` constructor.

2. What is causing f.tellg to give these strange values 0,6,7 instead of the expected 1,2,3 by default?

**possible explanation**(testing an answer by Holt below)

f.tellg in this code resorts to `f.rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, ios_base::cur, ios_base::in)` which is responsible for producing the values 0, 6, 7(but only if `ios_base::binary` is not specified at construction/open).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static char s[10];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ifstream f("file.txt");    
    cout << "position: " << f.rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, ios_base::cur, ios_base::in) << "\n";
    f.read(s, 1);
    cout << "got: " << s << "\n";
    cout << "position: " << f.rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, ios_base::cur, ios_base::in) << "\n";
    f.read(s, 1);
    cout << "got: " << s << "\n";
    cout << "position: " << f.rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, ios_base::cur, ios_base::in) << "\n";
    f.close();

    return 0;
}
```

**Note** passing `ios::in | ios::binary` as the second argument to the ifstream constructor makes both files behave as expected, but I would like to also know what's causing the default behavior to give these strange tellg values.

**Note** difference from [tellg() function give wrong size of file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984956/tellg-function-give-wrong-size-of-file). That question has ios::binary set by default, and uses seek; this question here has both ios::binary and without, and does not use seek. Overall, the two questions have different contexts, and knowing the answer to that question does not answer this one.

Comment: Compare the files in a hex editor. Maybe there's a BOM or some weird unseen crap at the start of the file, that the OS reads and skips for you (unless you open the file in binary mode).

Comment: added the hex views at the bottom. Both first 2 characters are the same, so I don't see how it would impact seekg.

Comment: What OS and compiler are you using? Please include the exact versions.

Comment: Windows, mingw, gcc 5.3.0

Comment: Maybe you actually need to open file as binary to read byte-by-byte? `std::ifstream f("file.txt", std::ios::binary);`

Comment: passing `ifstream::in | ifstream::binary`/`ios::in | ios::binary` as second argument to the ifstream constructor indeed fixes this. I am still curious what causes  the default mode to behave this way.

Comment: @Dmitry When a file is open in text mode, the return value of `tellg()` is unspecified (it is only meant to be used as an argument to `seekg()`).

Comment: @Holt Quote the appropriate section in the standard and turn it into an answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tellg() function give wrong size of file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984956/tellg-function-give-wrong-size-of-file)

Comment: @gsamaras Yes, though I think the answer here is better!

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing as a "wrong" result for a value returned by `tellg()`: when the file is opened in **text mode**, the return value is **unspecified** (i.e. it has no meaning except that it can be used as input for `seekg()`).

Basically, a call to `tellg()` on a `basic_fstream` falls back to the [`std::ftell`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/ftell)<sup>1</sup> function, which says (C standard, §7.21.9.4 [File positioning functions], emphasis is mine):

> `long int ftell(FILE *stream);`
>
> The `ftell` function obtains the current value of the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by `stream`. [...] For a text stream, its file position indicator **contains unspecified information**, usable by the `fseek` function for returning the file position indicator for the
>   stream to its position at the time of the `ftell` call; the difference between two such return values is **not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read.**

<sub><sup>1</sup> `tellg()` falls back to `rdbuf()->pubseekoff(0, std::ios_base::cur, std::ios_base::in)`, which falls back to `basic_filebuf::seekoff(0, std::ios_base::cur, std::ios_base::in)` which then falls back to `std::ftell()`.</sub>

Comment: I tested your answer by going to pubseekoff directly, and it indeed gives the same faulty values but only if the constructor of ifstream is not given `ios_base::in | ios_base::binary`. Still curious what's happening behind the scenes to produce these 1,6,7 results rather than 0, 1, 2.

Comment: @Dmitry This is highly OS (and compiler) dependent - In particular on Windows, you have some translation in text mode, e.g. for `'\n'`. I tried your code with your text file, and I did not even get the same results as you (I got 7 8 and 2 3). This is probably because I added an extra `'\n'`  at the end of each file, which would confirm the impact of the translation of `'\n'`  on Windows.