# Convert text document to a char array c++

Tags: c++, file, dynamic-arrays

I am attempting to convert text from a text document to a char array. To begin I tried to implement a dynamic array. However, for some reason when I attempt to save each char from the text into the new array it returns a bunch of equals signs. Down below is what I have:

Say for example the text said something like "Make this a char array".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char x;
    int y = 0;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("text.txt");
    while (file >> x)
        y++;

    char *phrase = NULL;
    phrase = new char[y];

    for (int i = 0; file >> x; i++)
    {
        phrase[i] = x;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < y; i++)
    {
        cout << phrase[i];
    }
}
```

It will end up outputting: "=================="

I did research on this issue but I couldn't find anything that clears it up.

Comment: You need to go back to the beginning of the file. You can't just keep reading the file after you have read everything to the end.

Comment: It would be easier to use a `std::vector` which will automatically resize its internal array as needed.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but don't do pointless initialization followed by modifying objects. Instead of `ifstream file; file.open("text.txt");` use `ifstream file("text.txt");`. Similarly, instead of `char *phrase = NULL; phrase = new char[y];` use `char *phrase = new char[y];`. Your code block doesn't go this far, but I'll bet there's `file.close()` further down; that's not needed, either: the destructor will close the file.

Comment: @einpoklum - I also helped mess it up, if that `iostream` was a cut-and-paste from mine. <g> In mine it's a spell-check-induced error. I took the liberty of fixing that in your answer.

Comment: (checking...) Oh yeah. Right. Wll, all's well that ends well.

Comment: I think douplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-read-an-entire-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be "measuring" the length of the file by repeatedly reading individual characters from it. You don't need to do that - just determine the size before opening the file:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>  

int main() {
    auto file_name { "text.txt" };
    auto size = std::filesystem::file_size(file_name);
    std::ifstream file(file_name);
    // etc. etc.
```

See the documentation for the [`file_size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size) function. It's in C++17; if you're using an earlier version of the language, try `>experimental/filesystem>` with C++14, or otherwise the [`boost::filesystem`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library with any version of C++.

... but actually, you don't need to do that *at all*!

You can just read the entire file using plain vanilla C++ standard library facilities:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("text.txt");
    if (not file) { /* handle error */ }
    std::stringstream sstr;
    sstr << file.rdbuf(); // magically read all of the file!
    auto entire_file_contents = sstr.str();
    const char* arr = entire_file_contents.c_str();
    // Now do whatever you like with the char array arr
}
```

See also this: [What is the best way to read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/116038/1593077)

By the way, it's kind of tricky to determine the size of a file given an  `std::ifstream` without sort-of reading the whole file, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22986486/1593077).

Comment: `not file`? Is this new syntax in c++17?

Comment: @davidshen84: [`not` is the same as `!`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) - and this equivalence is very  old actually. Also see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) about `ifstream`'s `operator!`.

Comment: @M.M: Already fixed a while ago I think. Plus, feel free to edit.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (file)` and `file.rdbuf()`?

Comment: @Barmar: No-but-I-should-fix-the-indentation, and yes, respectively. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("text.txt");
    std::vector<char> text;
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(file),
        std::istream_iterator<char>(),
        std::back_inserter(text));
    // now text holds the contents of the file
    // if you really need a char array, you can use text.data()
}
```

Note that the code does not test whether the file was opened successfully. I/O operations on streams are no-ops when the stream is in an error state. Yes, you can check if you prefer, but it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: +1, but I suggest you include some token error handling code anyway, as otherwise you're surreptitiously legitimizing failure to check errors generally.

Comment: Also, how fast is this? Are you sure it doesn't end up copying one character at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
std::ifstream file("text.txt", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
std::streamsize size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

std::vector<char> buffer(size);
if (file.read(buffer.data(), size))
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: This has different behaviour to the original intent of opening the file in text mode, on some operating systems