# Reading a UTF-8 file a parsing characters

Tags: c++

I originally had the below code using `std::wstring` and was using wide strings that were statically typed into the code.

Later I learned that UTF-8 will "fit" into `std::string` and that there was no real need for `std::wstring` but that I might need some encoding translations later on. So I have a UTF-8 encoded text file that I'm reading in.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class A
{
public:
    A(std::istream& stream)
    :
        m_stream(stream),
        m_lineNumber(1),
        m_characterNumber(1)
    {

    }

    bool OutputKnownWords()
    {
        while(m_stream.good())
        {
            if(Take("MIDDLE"))
                std::cout << "Found middle" << std::endl;
            else if(Take("BEGIN"))
                std::cout << "Found begin" << std::endl;
            else if(Take("END"))
                std::cout << "Found end" << std::endl;
            else if(Take(" "))
                std::cout << "parsed out space" << std::endl;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

protected:

    std::istream::char_type Get()
    {
        auto c = m_stream.get();
        ++m_characterNumber;
        if(c == '\n')
        {
            ++m_lineNumber;
            m_characterNumber = 1;
        }
        return c;
    }

    bool Take(const std::string& str)
    {
        if(!Match(str))
            return false;

        for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i)
            Get();

        return true;
    }

    bool Match(const std::string& str)
    {
        auto cursorPos = m_stream.tellg();

        std::string readStr(str.size(),'\0');

        m_stream.read(&readStr[0],str.size());

        if(std::size_t(m_stream.gcount()) < str.size() || readStr != str)
        {
            if(!m_stream.good())
                m_stream.clear();
            m_stream.seekg(cursorPos);
            return false;
        }
        m_stream.seekg(cursorPos);
        return true;
    }

    std::istream& m_stream;
    std::size_t m_lineNumber;
    std::size_t m_characterNumber;
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("test.txt");
    if(!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "could not open file" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    A a(file);

    if(!a.OutputKnownWords())
    {
        std::cerr << "something went wrong" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**text.text**

```
BEGIN MIDDLE
END
```

So I would expect that this program outputs:

```
Found begin
parsed out space
Found middle
parsed out space
Found end
```

However, `OutputKnownWords` returns an error. I stepped through with the debugger and I found that the `seekg` calls in `Match` appear to not be setting the correct position. It's like, each test is out by one character.

When I was doing this with wide strings statically typed I had no problem.

I sort of think this might be related to the difference between UTF-8 encoding vs `std::string`'s idea of a "character". But I'm not sure how then to handle how many "characters" are in an `std::string`.

This isn't related to [tellg() function give wrong size of file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984956) because I'm not doing anything with the cursor from `tellg` other than using it to reset the position.

Comment: Note that `while (m_stream.good())` is really not that different from `while (!m_stream.eof())`, and [`eof` inside a loop condition is generally always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: Thanks for the info @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Where is the UTF-8? Also, in order to get closer to a [mcve], you could use a stringstream, which would allow putting all this into one file.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the `test.txt` is UTF-8 encoded. It's in two files because I don't have an error when I use a `stringstream`.

Comment: Try opening the stream in binary mode, due to newline translations seeks in text file streams are unreliable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tellg() function give wrong size of file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984956/tellg-function-give-wrong-size-of-file)

Comment: @AlanBirtles that didn't do the trick

Comment: @AlanBirtles I don't believe it's to do with `tellg()` because I do no translations on it after calling it, I just use it to go back to whether I was before the `Match()` test.

Comment: 1. Run the test on a western encoded file. 2. Read about UTF-8 decoding.

Comment: @ZDF there should be a prize for most non-helpful comment. You would win.

Comment: There is no UTF-8 decoding in your code. Search std for UTF-8 decoding. Irony? - Love, Sheldon.

Comment: Use your debugger to step through the program. Find the point where the expected behaviour diverges from the actual behaviour. Observe the values of local variables. The problem has nothing to do with UTF-8 whatsoever.

Comment: @n.m. thanks for the suggestion. I've done this but I still can't work out the issue. Maybe you could copy and paste the code and show me where the problem is by posting an answer.

Comment: Pay special attention to `readStr` in `Match`. Does it always have the value you expect?

Comment: @n.m. no it doesn't. That's like the whole problem. Seekg to a position returned by tellg seems to be like "misaligned"

Comment: "Seekg to a position returned by tellg seems to be like "misaligned" No it isn't. Since you have the newline character in the string, it stands to reason that you have failed to read the newline character, rather than there's any tellg misalignment.

Comment: @n.m. reading a newline or not has no bearing on whether seekg to a cursor previously returned by tellg will work correctly.

Comment: Reading a newline or not has everything to do with the overall correctness of your program. If you don't read the newline correctly, your results will be wrong. You blame your wrong results on seekg/tellg but there's no evidence for it whatsoever. Did you rule out incorrect reading of the newline? How?

Comment: Let's try a minimal change. Add this: `else if(Take("\n")) std::cout << "parsed out newline" << std::endl;` Does it improve the results?

Comment: @n.m. I think you should read the comments on one of the answers to appreciate where the error is.

Comment: I think you should try what I have suggested befre alleging that I don't understand something in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much simpler and more efficient version of your code would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class A
{
public:
    A(std::istream& stream)
        :
        m_stream(stream),
        m_lineNumber(0),
        m_characterNumber(0)
    {

    }

    bool OutputKnownWords()
    {
        while (m_stream.good())
        {
            if (Take("MIDDLE"))
                std::cout << "Found middle" << std::endl;
            else if (Take("BEGIN"))
                std::cout << "Found begin" << std::endl;
            else if (Take("END"))
                std::cout << "Found end" << std::endl;
            else if (Take(" "))
                std::cout << "parsed out space" << std::endl;
            else
                return !m_stream.good();
        }
        return true;
    }

protected:

    bool Take(const std::string& str)
    {
        if (!Match(str))
            return false;

        m_characterNumber += str.size();

        return true;
    }

    bool readLine()
    {
        std::getline(m_stream, line);
        m_characterNumber = 0;
        m_lineNumber++;
        return !m_stream.eof();
    }

    bool Match(const std::string& str)
    {
        while (m_characterNumber >= line.size())
        {
            if (!readLine())
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (line.size() - m_characterNumber < str.size())
        {
            return false;
        }
        return line.substr(m_characterNumber, str.size()) == str;
    }

    std::istream& m_stream;
    std::size_t m_lineNumber;
    std::size_t m_characterNumber;
    std::string line;
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("test.txt");
    if (!file.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "could not open file" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    A a(file);

    if (!a.OutputKnownWords())
    {
        std::cerr << "something went wrong" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this seems to work. I note you're not using tellg and seekg. I would really like to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: @NeomerArcana seeking in text streams is unreliable (seems especially so in MinGW), as seeking is not necessary to implement your program I'd just go with the simpler option

Comment: This works and after some research, windows seeking in text mode is a bit broken.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are ultimately trying to achieve but your code seems unnecessarily complex and difficult to understand and debug. There are a couple of issues. The first is that you never consume the newline character as you only call `Get` for the number of characters in your string (if you debug you'll notice that the string you read in `Match` is `"\nEN"` instead of `"END"`. The second is that if you try to read a string but the stream doesn't return the requested number of characters you clear the error flags and return, this means you'll never reach the end of the file and your while condition of `stream.good()` will never fail.

To fix these issues change `Match` to:

```
bool Match(const std::string& str)
{
    auto cursorPos = m_stream.tellg();
    if (m_stream.peek() == '\n')
    {
        //consume the newline
        Get();
        cursorPos = m_stream.tellg();
    }

    std::string readStr(str.size(), '\0');

    m_stream.read(&readStr[0], str.size());
    if (m_stream.gcount() == 0)
    {
        // must be at EOF
        return false;
    }
    if (std::size_t(m_stream.gcount()) < str.size() || readStr != str)
    {
        std::cout << "expected '" << str << "' actual '" << readStr << "'\n";
        if (!m_stream.good())
            m_stream.clear();
        m_stream.seekg(cursorPos);
        return false;
    }
    m_stream.seekg(cursorPos);
    return true;
}
```

change `OutputKnownWords` to:

```
bool OutputKnownWords()
{
    while (m_stream.good())
    {
        if (Take("MIDDLE"))
            std::cout << "Found middle" << std::endl;
        else if (Take("BEGIN"))
            std::cout << "Found begin" << std::endl;
        else if (Take("END"))
            std::cout << "Found end" << std::endl;
        else if (Take(" "))
            std::cout << "parsed out space" << std::endl;
        else
            // stream can only be not good at EOF
            return !m_stream.good();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't fix the core problem. The output `expected 'MIDDLE' actual 'BEGIN '
Found begin
expected 'MIDDLE' actual ' MIDDL'
expected 'BEGIN' actual 'IDDLE'
expected 'END' actual 'IDD'
expected ' ' actual 'I'
something went wrong` might explain what is happening.

Comment: @NeomerArcana it works for me, did you try debugging? What platform and compiler are you using?

Comment: Yeah, I'm debugging. Using Windows 10, mingw-builds 7.3.0

Comment: Possibly a bug in the mingw stream implementation? Almost looks like peek is consuming a character

Comment: Also looks the stream is being opened in text mode, which can cause problems due to how it attempts to handle CRLF as line terminator.  (It tries to be helpful, and often the CRLF handling is helpful.  Except when it doesn't work well, such as trying to treat the file as binary.)

Comment: @Eljay seems to be going wrong before it reaches the newline though according to the above debug output.