# C++17 filesystem call generates segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++17

Based on the response to [Size of file using C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56827878/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-with-c17), I wrote the following program. But, when the executable is run, I get a segmentation fault. I am using g++ 8.3.0 on an iMac running High Sierra.

```
// c17filesize.cpp
// Jul-02-2019

#include <cstring>
#include <filesystem>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char filename[100];
    (argc > 1) ? strcpy(filename, argv[1]) : strcpy(filename, __FILE__);
    auto size = filesystem::file_size(filename);
}
```

Comment: It is not filesystem, but your code segfauls. Always use strncpy, instead of strcpy. Here you don't need either - just use std::string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling with gcc 9.1.0 went through successfully without any qualms.

Answer (score 3):

1. Prefer using string (and its contructor) over c style strings.
2. according https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size you must specify full path. Did you verify argv[1] holds a full path?
3. check the file exist before attempting to read its size std::filesystem::exists(filename);
4. use try and catch sections to catch an exception.

Comment: (2) - Where does it say that you need a full path? (3),(4) - It's a good advice, but it can't case a segfault.

Answer (score 2):

Just bumped into segfault whilst using std::filesystem:exists.

With GCC 8.3. Had to link with -lstdc++fs to solve the problem.

Note: GCC 9+ solves this problem (https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-9/changes.html)