# Debug Assertion Failed buffer != nullptr

Tags: c++, ifstream, assertion

Here is my code:

```
    ifstream ifile;
    list<unsigned char> fbinary;

    ifile.open(filename, ios::binary);
    if (ifile.fail() || !ifile.is_open())
        return false;

    ifile.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int sz = ifile.tellg();
    if (sz <= 0)
        return false;

    try
    {
        //Get Binary And Encrypt with XOR
        ifile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        unsigned char temp = 0;
        while (ifile)
        {
            ifile.read((char*)temp, sizeof(unsigned char));
            temp ^= Encrypt_Key;
            fbinary.push_back(temp);
        }

        ifile.close();
    }
    ...
```

`file.open` and getting file size don't fail. I don't know why `ifile.read()` fires debug assertion.

Error Message:

> Expression : buffer != nullptr

Comment: I see neither debug assertion, nor a variable `buffer` in this code.

Comment: Please provide the full error message. There are going to be more lines before or after the one you included in the question. Also a [repro] is required here for debugging help.

Comment: The linked image gives a 404 and you are supposed to edit the error message as plain text into the question. See [ask].

Comment: @64BitO2 Any relevant code (and error message) should be *in the question*, as *text*. Not behind external links.

Comment: General advice: If you write an explicit cast like in `(char*)temp`, you better make really really sure that you know what it is doing. I think you didn't do that here. Also prefer `static_cast<...>(...)` instead of C-style casts, as they are a bit safer.

Comment: `(char*)temp` should be `&temp`.

Comment: @Evg &temp is unsgined char* and (char*)temp is char*. not same

Comment: @64BitO2 Then why are you not declaring `temp` as `char`?

Comment: @uneven_mark, you're right. :) Moreover, it will always fail, because `char` and `unsigned char` are unconditionally different types.

Comment: @Evg Oh right, it doesn't actually matter, it is always wrong.

Comment: @uneven_mark i changed unsgined char to char, and it works. but i don't understand what is the matter.

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear what `buffer` is (it's likely to be a variable inside the standard library implementation), but the code in the question has at least one blatant error:

```
unsigned char temp = 0;
... 
ifile.read((char*)temp, sizeof(unsigned char));
```

Here you first initialize `temp` with zero, then convert it into a pointer, which is actually a null pointer. Calling `.read()` with a null pointer is UB -  there is no valid memory buffer at the location `(char*)temp (= nullptr)`.

What you want, is probably this:

```
char temp;
... 
ifile.read(&temp, sizeof(char));
```

Here you pass the valid address of `temp` into `.read()`.

Also note that getting file size from `tellg()` can give an incorrect result. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984956/tellg-function-give-wrong-size-of-file).

Answer (score -4):

Try calling ifile.clear() before you seek the beginning, inside the try block:

try
    {
       // call clear
        ifile.clear();
        //Get Binary And Encrypt with XOR
        ifile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
        unsigned char temp = 0;
        while (ifile)
        {

Comment: This is not at all the problem here.

Comment: Don't just guess when posting an answer, please.