# tellg() and tellp() function in file handling is showing unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, database, file

This is my code below.

Here the output is (Hi 5). If I remove the third line(use to) output is (Hi 4). Technically output should be (Hi 3) but tellg() is increasing with every increase in line.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
void main(){
fstream file("d.txt",ios::trunc | ios::in | ios::out);
string c;
file<<"Hi there"<<endl;
file<<"good evil"<<endl;
file<<"use to"<<endl;
file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
file>>c;
cout<<c<<" "<<file.tellg()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: you should probably add `using namespace std;` and change `void main()` to `int main()` because otherwise it doesn't compile. Besides that, I get `Hi 2` as output no matter how many line I enter. What operating system and compiler are you on?

Comment: @Leonid I am on windows and i have compiled the code with my terminal. I got an o/p of Hi 5

Comment: tellg() has no meaningful value for text files.  The stream needs to read ahead to deal with multi-byte encodings and line ending quirks.  Ideally it would hide those quirks, but ideals are hard to come by in iostream land.  Only use it for ios::binary files.  Or not at all, a common conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

The standard actually doesn't guarantee any specific value for `tellg`, only that if `seekg` is run sometime afterwards on its output, it will put the stream into the same place that it was. In any case, the output of `tellg` is implementation-defined. It doesn't even have to be convertible to an integral type. In terms of implementations, generally files opened in binary mode (and in text mode for *nix systems) will produce `tellg` output equal to the byte offset from the beginning of the file, while in text mode (non-*nix systems) producing some value greater or equal to the byte offset.

For a specific reason why `tellg` was increasing by 1 each time you added a line, one possible factor that may have influenced this implementation-defined behaviour in your compiler might be the fact that the Windows line terminator `\n\r` is two bytes instead of one. Of course, relying on implementation-defined behaviour is generally a bad idea.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22986486