# A 'stack overflow' error returns upon any array size I enter above 36603. How can I make a string capable of capturing my entire .txt file?

Tags: c++

I need to create a string capable of holding the entire book 'The Hunger Games' which comes out to around 100500 words. My code can capture samples of the txt, but anytime I exceed a string size of 36603(tested), I receive a 'stack overflow' error.

I can successfully capture anything below 36603 elements and can output them perfectly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int i;
    char set[100];
    string fullFile[100000]; // this will not execute if set to over 36603

    ifstream myfile("HungerGames.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        // saves 'i limiter' words from the .txt to fullFile
        for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            //each word is saparated by a space
            myfile.getline(set, 100, ' ');
            fullFile[i] = set;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    //prints 'i limiter' words to window
    for (i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        cout << fullFile[i] << ' ';
    }
```

What is causing the 'stack overflow' and how can I successfully capture the txt? I will later be doing a word counter and word frequency counter, so I need it in "word per element" form.

Comment: Unrelated `char set[100];` - *terrible* name for a user-defined identifier, especially in a program that has `using namespace std;` in the source ([the more-important issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)). That's a recipe for a wtf-compiler error down the road.

Comment: Above you mention  "I can capture anything below 36603 elements", and for fullFile array the elements are strings.  But you then mention some idea of "string size of 36603(tested)"   Confusing.  I think you mean that your code stack-overflows when the array size xxxxxx ( in fullFile[xxxxxx] ) is bigger than 36603... This is how many strings are in the array. (not a string size).

Answer (score 3):

There's a limit on how much stack is used in a function; Use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

More [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310658/how-much-stack-usage-is-too-much) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825964/c-c-maximum-stack-size-of-program). The default in Visual studio is 1MB (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/f-set-stack-size?view=vs-2019)) and you can change it with /F, but this is a bad idea generally.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. We (my class) haven't gone into vectors yet so I don't know how to use it. I'll use your links above to see If I can implement it effectively.

Answer (score 0):

My system is Lubuntu 18.04, with g++ 7.3.  The following snippet shows some "implementation details" of my system, and how to report them on yours.  It would help you to understand what your system provides ...

```
void foo1()
{
   int i;                                              //  Lubuntu
   cout << "\n  sizeof(i)    "  << sizeof(i) << endl;  //   4 bytes

   char c1[100];
   cout << "\n  sizeof(c1)   "  << sizeof(c1) << endl;  // 100 bytes

   string s1; // empty string
   cout << "\n  s1.size()    "  << s1.size()            // 0  bytes
        << "    sizeof(s1)   "  << sizeof(s1) << endl;  // 32 bytes

   s1 = "1234567890"; // now has 10 chars
   cout << "\n  s1.size()    "  << s1.size()            // 10 bytes
        << "    sizeof(s1)   "  << sizeof(s1) << endl;  // 32 bytes

   string fullFile[100000]; // this is an array of 100,000 strings
   cout << "\n  sizeof(fullFile)   "           // total is vvvvvvvvv
        << sops.digiComma(sizeof(fullFile)) << endl;  // 3,200,000 bytes

   uint64_t totalChars = 0;
   for( auto ff : fullFile ) totalChars += ff.size();
   cout << "\n  total chars in all strings " << totalChars << endl;
}
```

> What is causing the 'stack overflow' and how can I successfully
>   capture the txt?

The fullFile array is an unfortunate choice ... because each std::string, even when empty, consumes 32 bytes of automatic memory (~stack), for a total of 3,200,000 bytes, and this is with no data in the strings!  This will stack overflow your system when the stack is smaller than the automatic var space.

On Lubuntu the default automatic-memory size (lately) is 10 M Bytes, so not a problem for me.  But you will have to check on what your version of your target os defaults to.  I think Windows defaults down near 1 M Byte.  (Sorry, I don't know how to check Windows automatic-memory size.)

---

> How can I make a string capable of capturing my entire .txt file.

The answer is -- **you don't need to make your own**.   (unless you have some unstated requirement)

Also, you really should look at en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append".

---

In my 1st snippet above, you should take notice that the sizeof(string) reports 32 bytes, regardless of how many chars are in it.

Think on that a while ... if you put 1000 chars into a string, where do they go?  The objects stays at 32 bytes!  You might guess or read that the string object handles memory management on your behalf, and puts all characters into dynamic-memory (heap).

On my system, heap is about 4 G bytes.  That's a lot more than stack.

In summary, every **single** std::string expands auto-magically, using heap, so if your text input will fit in heap, it will fit into '1 std::string'.

While browsing around in the cppreference, check out the 'string::reserve()' command.

---

Conclusion:

Any std::string you declare can auto-magically 'grow' to support your need, and will thus hold the entire text (if it will fit in memory).

Operationally, you simply get a line of text from the file, then append it to the single string, until the entire file is contained.  You only need the one array, which std::string provides.

With this new idea ... I suggest you change fullFile from an array to a string.

```
string  fullFile;  // file will expand to handle append actions
                   // to the limit of available heap.

// open file ... check status

do {
   myfile.getline(line); // fetch line of text up thru the line feed 
                         // Note that getline does not put the \n into 'line'

   // there are file state checks that should be done (perhaps here?)

   // tbd - line += '\n';   
   // you may need the line feed in your fullFile string?

   fullFile += line;    // append the line 

} while (!myfile.eof);  // check for eof

// ... other file cleanup.
```

---

foo1() output on Lubuntu 18.04, g++ v7.3

```
sizeof(i)    4

sizeof(c1)   100

s1.size()    0    sizeof(s1)   32

s1.size()    10    sizeof(s1)   32

sizeof(fullFile)   3,200,000

total chars in all strings 0
```

---

Example slurp() :

```
string  slurp(ifstream& sIn)
{
   stringstream ss;
   ss << sIn.rdbuf();
   dtbAssert(!sIn.bad());
   if(sIn.bad())
       throw "\n  DTB::slurp(sIn)  'ss << sIn.rdbuf()' is bad";
   ss.clear(); // clear flags
   return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: Alternative 1 of many:  replace " string fullFile[100000]; "  with  " string* fullFile[100000]; ", (and initialization, and delete code).  This moves 3.2 million bytes (of std::string objects) from stack to heap, replaced by  400,000 (or 800,000) bytes of pointers on the stack.  Your post gives me no insight into how you plan to use the fullFile array, this is smaller deviation from your original idea.

Comment: If your text file exceeds your systems heap limits, I believe you might consider working with the data in-the-file mode, using seek, reads, writes, etc.  I know little about that kind of effort.

Comment: Alternative 2 of many:  use somebody's C++ "slurp()". It reads an entire file into a stringstream (ss) in some ways minimal code. AND returns the string of the ss.  I have 2 versions, each has a tradeoff.  I also found  4 variations picked for performance (at some reduction of readability) at https://stackoverflow.com/a/524843/2785528.