# Read file-contents into a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, file-io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to slurp a file into a std::string in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c)

In scripting languages like Perl, it is possible to read a file into a variable in one shot.

```
    open(FILEHANDLE,$file);
    $content=<FILEHANDLE>;
```

What would be the most efficient way to do this in C++?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"?

Comment: Efficient = fast and not using much memory.

Comment: similar question: [Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2602013/97160)

Answer (score 248, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  std::ifstream ifs("myfile.txt");
  std::string content( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                       (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );

  return 0;
}
```

The statement

```
  std::string content( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                       (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
```

can be split into

```
std::string content;
content.assign( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
```

which is useful if you want to just overwrite the value of an existing std::string variable.

Comment: +1 Very C++ idiomatic. In Linux with gcc 4.4 the resulting system calls are efficient, the file is read 8k at a time.

Comment: If the file size is known, the `std::string::reserve` method can be called before reading the file to allocate space.  This should speed up the execution.  Much time is lost by reallocating memory for the string.

Comment: +1, but why do the iterators *have* to be enclosed in parenthesis? They seem innocuous but it won't compile without them.

Comment: Qix: it's the "classic" c++ parsing problem called Most Vexing Parse: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: I tried the above content.assign( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ), command. Works well read all the file but when i display the contents it shows invalid character at the beginning. why ??
Help.

'code'
    string content;
    ifstream myfile("textFile.txt");
    content.assign( (istreambuf_iterator<char>(myfile) ),
                       (istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
     cout<<content;

Comment: In VS2010, how to pass this "content" to a function definition for example AtoB(std::string); Any further example?

Comment: @MartijnPieters why the second parameter is an empty iterator and not related to ifs? I guess you are using this: [basic_string& assign (InputIterator first, InputIterator last)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/basic_string/assign/)

Comment: @aburbanol: I'm not the author of this post; I only dealt with cleaning up a bad edit here.

Comment: Is there any way to check the read was successful (or not) with this method?

Comment: It seems \r\n is translated into \n, how to avoid this?

Comment: Why the extra parentheses around iterators? Makes the code more messy IMO :)

Comment: This compiles without parentheses at least on `GCC 5.5.0` and `GCC 7.3.0` on my Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: i was woundering about `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()`, but this is the `end-of-stream iterator`. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator

Comment: It will throw exception `basic_filebuf:underflow`, if the file from udisk, and the udisk is pulled out. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 46):

The most efficient, but not the C++ way would be:

```
   FILE* f = fopen(filename, "r");

   // Determine file size
   fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
   size_t size = ftell(f);

   char* where = new char[size];

   rewind(f);
   fread(where, sizeof(char), size, f);

   delete[] where;
```

### `#`EDIT - 2

Just tested the `std::filebuf` variant also. Looks like it can be called the best C++ approach, even though it's not quite a C++ approach, but more a wrapper. Anyway, here is the chunk of code that works almost as fast as plain C does.

```
   std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
   std::streambuf* raw_buffer = file.rdbuf();

   char* block = new char[size];
   raw_buffer->sgetn(block, size);
   delete[] block;
```

I've done a quick benchmark here and the results are following. Test was done on reading a *65536K* binary file with appropriate (`std::ios:binary` and `rb`) modes.

```
[==========] Running 3 tests from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 4 tests from IO
[ RUN      ] IO.C_Kotti
[       OK ] IO.C_Kotti (78 ms)
[ RUN      ] IO.CPP_Nikko
[       OK ] IO.CPP_Nikko (106 ms)
[ RUN      ] IO.CPP_Beckmann
[       OK ] IO.CPP_Beckmann (1891 ms)
[ RUN      ] IO.CPP_Neil
[       OK ] IO.CPP_Neil (234 ms)
[----------] 4 tests from IO (2309 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 4 tests from 1 test case ran. (2309 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 4 tests.
```

Comment: +1 this was going to be my answer. Although, you should add the allocation of `where` for the example to be more clear: `char *where = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);`

Comment: As far as I know, there is a chance that std::filebuf in the C++ library is more efficient

Comment: Nice benchmark, I'm not surprised by the numbers.  For max performance on plain ascii files using good old C io is the way to go.  C++ streams are just no match.  However, they are less error prone. As long as they are not showing up when profiling I'd prefer using them.

Comment: You have to try with std::filebuf s :)

Comment: Wow, it's actually cool. I don't know why, but at first I didn't trust you. Looks like the best way to combine `iostream` functionality and raw C file reading speed.

Comment: Heh.. plain C is STILL faster ;)

Comment: Can you compare using `getline(file, string, string::traits_type::to_char_type(string::traits_type::eof())`?

Comment: @Constantino, you method of determining file length is improper. Although fstat/rewing combination works, the proper way is filling stat struct and extracting st_size member. It is better to be on the safe side.

Comment: how do you find size here?!

Answer (score 14):

The most efficient is to create a buffer of the correct size and then read the file into the buffer.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream       file("Plop");
    if (file)
    {
        /*
         * Get the size of the file
         */
        file.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
        std::streampos          length = file.tellg();
        file.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);

        /*
         * Use a vector as the buffer.
         * It is exception safe and will be tidied up correctly.
         * This constructor creates a buffer of the correct length.
         * Because char is a POD data type it is not initialized.
         *
         * Then read the whole file into the buffer.
         */
        std::vector<char>       buffer(length);
        file.read(&buffer[0],length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Benchmarks? Or even strace... (not that I don't believe this is the fastest, I do wonder whether it is actually any different from the iterator-based approach)

Comment: This method is not guaranteed to work. `tellg` is not specified to return the offset into the file in bytes - it's just an opaque token. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22986486/1505939) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: In text mode, on an operating system that performs file translations, it is likely that the result of `tellg` will not match the number of characters available to be read

Answer (score 8):

There should be no `\0` in text files.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  fstream f(FILENAME, fstream::in );
  string s;
  getline( f, s, '\0');

  cout << s << endl;
  f.close();
}
```

Comment: The question didn't mention text files.

Comment: -1 This example only reads one line, I have to wonder about the moderations.

Comment: @piotr This example reads the whole text file, it is tested.

Comment: I think everybody assume it would be a text file but it's true it may not be the case.

As far as the code goes: maybe it's clearer to directly use ifstream( "filename" ). 

You don't need to close the file, it is done automatically. And it does read the text file.

Comment: @Draco Ater I tested with a binary file, probably it did read only until \0. The point is that this example is going to process every character, I prefer iterator based solutions that may be more efficient.

Comment: This works beautifully. It's the most relevant answer in this entire thread in my opinion. Stores the whole shebang in a C++ string, not a char array. Thanks Draco!

Comment: @MartynChamberlin the other solutions which store in a `vector<char>` could be modified to store in a `string` by changing the text `vector<char>` to `string`

Comment: This is the simplest (and best) solution here.  +1

Answer (score 4):

This depends on a lot of things, such as what is the size of the file, what is its type (text/binary) etc. Some time ago I benchmarked the following function against versions using streambuf iterators - it was about twice as fast:

```
unsigned int FileRead( std::istream & is, std::vector <char> & buff ) {
    is.read( &buff[0], buff.size() );
    return is.gcount();
}

void FileRead( std::ifstream & ifs, string & s ) {
    const unsigned int BUFSIZE = 64 * 1024; // reasoable sized buffer
    std::vector <char> buffer( BUFSIZE );

    while( unsigned int n = FileRead( ifs, buffer ) ) {
        s.append( &buffer[0], n );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

maybe not the most efficient, but reads data in one line:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>

main(int argc,char *argv[]){
  // read standard input into vector:
  std::vector<char>v(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin),
                     std::istream_iterator<char>());
  std::cout << "read " << v.size() << "chars\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an iterator-based method.

```
ifstream file("file", ios::binary);
string fileStr;

istreambuf_iterator<char> inputIt(file), emptyInputIt
back_insert_iterator<string> stringInsert(fileStr);

copy(inputIt, emptyInputIt, stringInsert);
```