# C++ spaces mark end of input in cin?

Tags: c++, cin

I'm just learning some stuff about cryptography and I made a cool program to encrypt any message by rotating the letters through the alphabet a given number of letters...anyway...I have it all set up but I can't give it multiple words to encrypt because it ends the input after one word...(using cin)...how would I get cin to not stop taking input until I hit return?

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912520/read-file-contents-into-a-string-in-c/2912614#2912614) might be useful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `std::getline()`?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline.html

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string line;
getline( std::cin, line );
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/) to read a full line.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`cin.getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) to read a line?  (Or, probably better, as Martin notes in a comment, use [`std::getline`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/).)

Comment: prefer std::getline() as you are not dealing with fixed size buffers.