# How to read any file safely into a string?

Tags: c++, string, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to slurp a file into a std::string in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c)

I'm trying to imitate PHP's file_get_contents() function for C++.

However, when I convert a char array into a string, it stops at nullbyte:

```
fread(charbuf, 1, file_size, fp);
string str(charbuf);
```

How can I initialize the string as a static size array, and read the file contents directly to that container? Also, how do I check the errors for it, for example if there is not enough memory for initializing that string. This would also get me rid of the temporary memory allocation I'm currently using, which I would like to get rid of.

How about safety? Is it possible that many processes read the same file at same time and/or one of them writes in it at same time when I am reading it? How do I avoid such things happening?

I hope you can answer other way than "string isn't binary container".

**I ask to reopen this question for the fact:** "Apparently, this question is as relevant as ever: two years later, the two most efficient solutions still copy the whole file contents in memory, and this copy cannot be elided by the optimizer. This is a quite unsatisfactory state of affairs. – Konrad Rudolph Oct 25 '10 at 6:25" at [What is the best way to read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c) Or do you want me to create new question that asks to read a file without having extra copy of the string?

Comment: Do you have any problems with using `ifstream`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912520/read-file-contents-into-a-string-in-c

Comment: @loler, does that allocate only that amount of memory as the file_size would be? or does it create temporary copy of the string? (for example if the file is 100MB, does it have 200MB allocated at some phase of the program?).

Comment: **Isn't it funny** that this "exact duplicate" has -2 votes, but the duplicate has +18 votes? I guess its not that exact duplicate as you thought.

Comment: No, it isn't funny, nor unexpected. One of the things that contributes to the perceived quality of a question is the research that went into it. There are at least two excellent questions on this subject already; this question may have been downvoted because you didn't find them.

Comment: Also, string _is_ a binary container. It can contain NUL just fine, and it makes no assumptions whatsoever about what is being stored, not even endianness, for example.

Comment: **I ask to reopen this question for the fact:** "Apparently, this question is as relevant as ever: two years later, the two most efficient solutions still copy the whole file contents in memory, and this copy cannot be elided by the optimizer. This is a quite unsatisfactory state of affairs. – Konrad Rudolph Oct 25 '10 at 6:25" at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c Or do you want me to create new question that asks to read a file without having extra copy of the string?

Answer (score 6):

```
std::ifstream fin("somefile.txt");
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << fin.rdbuf();
std::string result = buffer.str();
```

This snippet will put all your file into std::string

Comment: there is extra memory allocation too: you convert (copy) buffer to string... i want to avoid all that and just read it directly to string container without any side-allocations.

Comment: present compilers have rvo-value optimization. No problem with temporary object here.

Comment: @Rookie honestly what do you care about one allocation more or less, unless you're on an embedded system, it isn't going to slow you down that much.

Comment: @TonyTheLion, i like to make it good, instead of "enough good". it hurts my brain to see its having a copy of something, which is waste of memory and time.

Comment: @Rookie: I can understand the sentiment. However, many C++ constructs that *look* like they are copying data actually don't. (That's not because C++ is stupid, to the contrary: It is because C++ can optimize some things that other languages cannot.) First rule of optimization: Measure, optimize, measure.

Comment: @DevSolar, oh, so this stringstream isnt actually copying the data, just the pointer? But what happens when the `buffer` is destroyed? Thats why i thought it must be copying the data...

Comment: @DevSolar, you are wrong: "Apparently, this question is as relevant as ever: two years later, the two most efficient solutions still copy the whole file contents in memory, and this copy cannot be elided by the optimizer. This is a quite unsatisfactory state of affairs. – Konrad Rudolph Oct 25 '10 at 6:25" at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c

Comment: @Rookie: Read again what I *said*, not what you did read into it. That comment is two years old, and you still didn't measure if you actually have a problem if you do it this way, or if it simply doesn't matter because the matrix multiplication in the critical path of your application needs three orders of magnitude more RAM and CPU (or the buffer handling has been optimized by other people in the meantime).

Comment: @DevSolar, its not really about optimization here, its about doing it right, instead of doing it "enough good". i could as well get a kick in my nuts every day, just because you say it doesnt reduce my work-time much. it still hurts, though, but i would like to get rid of that pain since **it is not needed**.

Comment: @Rookie: Which brings us right back to square one: "I understand the sentiment..." I really do. But you *still* haven't measured whether *your* compiler can optimize the call in *your* library. And, as unfortunate as it is to perfectionists like you (and me), outside the critical path simplicity and readability trump optimization. (That's a statement with over twelve years hands-on experience behind it.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16965/discussion-between-devsolar-and-rookie)

Answer (score 0):

> *I hope you can answer other way than "string isn't binary container.*

`std::string` **is** a binary container, but the constructor you chose takes a C-style string as an argument. Try a different constructor:

```
std::fread(charbuf, 1, file_size, fp);
std::string str(charbuf, file_size);
```

---

**EDIT**: Taking into account requirement to avoid memory allocations:

```
std::string str(file_size, 0);
std::fread(&str[0], 1, file_size, fp);
```

Comment: the problem here is that i need to allocate charbuf and then free it... so if i read 100MB file, i have 200MB data allocated at same time (for char* and std:string). it would be more efficient if i only had 100MB data allocated at once.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c.

Comment: that seems to be exaclty what the other guy here told, it still is using a temporary memory, so i get 200MB allocated at same time for 100MB file.

Comment: could i perhaps use str.resize() somehow...? seems to have such function.

Comment: that is same as the other guy (seems like he removed his post now); it has wasteful memory assignment to zeroes. he told that it cannot be avoided... thats a pity.

Comment: @Rookie honestly you're being silly. That is not going to make a difference in performance.  Have  you measured if it that would cause a bottleneck? I have my doubts

Comment: @TonyTheLion, well if its not possible to avoid that, i guess its my only go... but i just wonder, how does it do it internally? if i could get that code, i could get rid of memset() line of code. I really dont understand whats the point setting the memory which will be ultimately replaced with something else anyways.

Comment: @Rookie mostly the point of doing `memset` is to fill with zero bytes, because you don't want to have memory full of garbage. At least for null bytes you can check, you can't check for junk

Comment: @TonyTheLion, indeed, but why would i need to check the data, if i check if the fread() function was successful?

Comment: To reserve space without initializing, use [std::string::reserve](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/reserve) of course. And yes the performance _may_ be a factor if the file was actually a kernel special character device with a zero-copy path or something silly like that. Of course, _memory mapped files_ beat the crap out of all of these approaches.

Comment: @sehe, looks like reserve() works as i wanted!? why did nobody say this before in all those 10 topics? Is that safe to use then?

Comment: @Rookie because it doesn't work. You can't `fread` into a `std::string` for a very simple reason: how do you make `str.size()` return the correct value? (hint: `str.resize()` will overwrite everything with zeroes).

Comment: Hmm. Sadly I was mentally confusing resize and reserve. @R.MartinhoFernandes is right. Will post another idea at the other answer

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, so i guess the resize() method is best for avoiding extra memory allocations?

Comment: @Rookie No, the resize method behaves more-or-less identically to the 2-argument constructor. It allocates memory and initializes all of the members. So, in terms of theoretical performance, they are equal. In terms of practical performance, you need to measure it in your own environment.

Comment: Aaaaahhh! My eyes! Are you *seriously* using a C function to pump data into the innards of a C++ object, and advertising that as good practice? Please don't touch any of my projects...