# Why are extra parenthesis in file read function?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, ifstream

I understand that the following code ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912520/read-file-contents-into-a-string-in-c)) is used to read the contents of a file to string:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

  std::ifstream ifs("myfile.txt");
  std::string content( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                       (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );
```

However, I don't understand why such seemingly redundant parentheticals are required. For example, the following code does not compile:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

  std::ifstream ifs("myfile.txt");
  std::string content(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs),
                      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()    );
```

Why are so many parentheses are needed for this to compile?

Comment: The second one is a function declaration. [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

Comment: To prevent [the most vexing parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because without the parentheses, the compiler treats it as a function declaration, declaring a function named `content` that returns a `std::string` and takes as arguments a `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` named `ifs` and a nameless parameter that is a function taking no arguments that returns a `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`.

You can either live with the parens, or as Alexandre notes in the comments, you can use the uniform initialisation feature of C++ which has no such ambiguities:

```
std::string content { std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() };
```

Or as Loki mentions:

```
std::string content = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Comment: Note: In C++11 you can do `std::string content{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()};`

Comment: Or you can use: `std::string content = std::string( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());`

Comment: Or even ``auto content = std::string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs),  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());``