# Take file contents and put it into a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, file-io, constructor

I'm using OpenGL and I need the contents of VertexShader.glsl to be put into a std::string

I've looked at the related StackOverflow posts about this but I don't really know how to match together data types and stuff to make it work.

Take for example this from [Read file-contents into a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912520/read-file-contents-into-a-string-in-c)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

  std::ifstream ifs("myfile.txt");
  std::string content( (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs) ),
                       (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()    ) );

  return 0;
}
```

I have no clue what's happening after

> std:: string content

Every time I have used std::string before has been like

```
std::string name = "2bdkid";
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's [constructor #6 here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Which does:

> Constructs the string with the contents of the range `[first, last)`.

[`istreambuf_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) is:

> a single-pass input iterator that reads successive characters from the `std::basic_streambuf` **(`ifs` in this example)** object for which it was constructed... The default-constructed `std::istreambuf_iterator` is known as the end-of-stream iterator. When a valid `std::istreambuf_iterator` reaches the end of the underlying stream, it becomes equal to the end-of-stream iterator.

`content` is constructed from an iterator pair - the first one of which is our single-pass iterator into the file, and the second of which is the end-of-stream iterator that acts as a sentinel. The range `[first, last)` that the `string` constructor refers to is, in this case, the full contents of the file.