# converting (file reading) function return value to c_str() not behaving as expected

Tags: c++, string

I have a function that reads a file and returns a string.

```
string get_file_contents(const char *filename)
{
    ifstream in(filename);
    if (in)
    {
        ostringstream contents;
        contents << in.rdbuf();
        in.close();
        return(contents.str());
    }
    throw(errno);
}
```

I read a file containing only `success` and convert the return value it into a `c` style string in two different ways with different results.

```
string str = get_file_contents("test.txt");
const char* str1 = str.c_str();
cout << "printing str1: ";
cout << str1 << endl;
const char* str2 = get_file_contents("test.txt").c_str();
cout << "printing str2: ";
cout << str2 << endl;
```

output:

```
printing str1: success
printing str2:
```

I don't understand why str2 is empty. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function call returns a string which is temporary in both cases.  Calling `c_str()` on that temporary returns a pointer that may be dangling after the statement completes.  Using the string to store the result is correct, which is why the first call works.  The second call may have undesirable effects due to the dangling pointer.

Since `str2` is a pointer, it's not simply empty, it's pointing to a non-existent string.  This could be a danger.

Storing the result into another string, as in the first call, might be optimized well by the compiler.

You may be able to shorten that file read as well:

```
...
ifstream in(filename);
if (in)
{
    return string(istreambuf_iterator<char>(in), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
}

// throw exception
...
```

Comment: Faster implementations are discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912520/read-file-contents-into-a-string-in-c also.

Answer (score 3):

With `str1` you are setting it to the internals of a local variable `str` which remains valid until it goes out of scope at the end of the function (as long as you don't modify `str`).

With `str2` you point it at the internals of a *temporary* string that is never assigned to a local variable and so it gets destroyed immediately after you assigned it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the pointer returned by `c_str()` remains valid only for as long as the string from which it is obtained is not modified or disposed.

When you do this

```
const char* str2 = get_file_contents("test.txt").c_str();
```

the string returned by `get_file_contents("test.txt")` is temporary. The call to `c_str()` returns a pointer to its internal content, but then the string gets destroyed, making the return invalid.

Comment: The proposed solution will work, but is uglier. You have also misunderstood the problem.