# fstream to const char *

Tags: c++, fstream

What I want to do is read a file called "test.txt", and then have the contents of the file be a type const char *.  How would one do this?

Comment: Are you sure you need a `const char *`? If you need something to pass into a function that takes `const char *`, then you can just pass in a `char *` if that's more convenient for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to slurp a file into a std::string in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
   std::string line,text;
   std::ifstream in("test.txt");
   while(std::getline(in, line))
   {
       text += line + "\n";
   }
   const char* data = text.c_str();
}
```

Be careful not to explicitly call delete on data

Comment: would `std::string text; std::getline(in, text, EOF); const char* data = text.c_str();` work faster?

Comment: I was planning to add another solution that uses sstream instead of string but I found the solution by eq-, which I strongly recommend over this one as it is much more efficient as you here allocate and free the memory with each line.

Answer (score 6):

It's highly unlikely you really want to do that. The contents of the file (which may be either text, or binary data) are unlikely to represent a (valid) pointer to a char on your architecture, so it is not really meaningful to represent it [the content] as a `const char *`.

What you may instead want is to load the contents of the file in memory, and then store a pointer (of type const char*) to the beginning of the given block. </pedantry> One way of achieving that:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
// ...
{
    std::ostringstream sstream;
    std::ifstream fs("test.txt");
    sstream << fs.rdbuf();
    const std::string str(sstream.str());
    const char* ptr = str.c_str();
    // ptr is the pointer we wanted - do note that it's only valid
    // while str is valid (i.e. not after str goes out of scope)
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I mess this up every time, which is odd since I usually learn from my mistakes. (I use stringstreams rarely, and "every time" I refer to the wrong header.) Fixed.

Comment: `do note that it's only valid while str is valid (i.e. not after str goes out of scope)` -- +1 for this. I had a similar solution but I was returning a `const char* ptr` from a function and couldn't figure out why things wasn't working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. create a function returning a const char*
2. open an `fstream` on the file
3. seek to its end
4. determine the file length by looking at the file position (`tell`)
5. seek back to the beginning
6. create a char* to contain the file contents
7. read the file contents into the char*
8. return the char* pointer, with the function return adding the const
9. the file is closed automatically by the fstream going out of scope