# Why C++ STL map is slow Java' s map class?

Tags: java, c++, stl

My input file is 2GB and in this file every line is a word. I need to write a program to do wordcount. I use Java and C++ do to the same task but result is surprising: C++ is too slow! My code are as follows:

C++:

```
int main() {

    struct timespec ts, te;
    double cost;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);

    map<string, int> map;    
    ifstream fin("inputfile.txt");
    string word;
    while(getline(fin, word)) {
        ++map[word];
    }

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &te);    
    cost = te.tv_sec - ts.tv_sec + (double)(te.tv_nsec-ts.tv_nsec)/NANO;
    printf("cost: %-15.10f s\n", cost);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:
    cost: 257.62 s

Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    FileReader reader = new FileReader("inputfile.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

    String str = null;
    while((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Integer count = map.get(str);
        map.put(str, count == null ? 1 : count + 1);
    }

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("cost : " + (endTime - startTime)/1000 + "s");
}
```

Output:
    cost: 124 s

I delete the code inside the while, just read the file but do not do anything, the result is  the same. Java cost: 32s, C++ cost: 38s. This gap I can accept.
My environment is Ubuntu Linux 13.04 and C++ use -O2 optimation.
Why does the STL perform poorly?

Comment: This might help you, your c++ implementation is bad, it is a broken pattern  `while(!EOF){...}`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8736862/c-whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-read-a-file-into-a-stdstring

Comment: Note that you are comparing mushrooms and apples again. Java is doing many things completely different here. E.g. in java strings are immutable and just references, in C++ they are copied into the tree.

Comment: While Björn's mentioned some important things already, there are many other possible factors - e.g. if you've just read the file off magnetic disk with C++, the content may still be in memory cache for Java, `FileReader` and/or `BufferedReader` might use a background thread, larger buffers, memory mapped or other higher-efficiency I/O mechanisms to reduce the number of `read` calls to the OS.  All these techniques are possible in C++ - you just have to choose the right mix of performance, simplicity, portability etc..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++ [`std::map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) is an ordered data-structure usually implemented as a tree. A fairer comparison would be between [`java.util.HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) and [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) or [`java.util.TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) and [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: Yes, I use the unordered_map, now C++ run faster than Java. Thank you!