# Read multiline file and using rdbuf()

Tags: c++, string, getline

I've a multiline file, every line a string.

Example of `code.txt`:

```
AAAAA
BB33A
C544W
```

I have to put some code contained in another file before every string. I'm using this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //the file to include before every string
    ifstream one("1.txt");

    //final output file
    ofstream final;
    final.open ("final.txt", ofstream::app);

    //string file
    string line;
    ifstream file("code.txt");

    while (getline(file,line))
    {
       final<<one.rdbuf();
       final<<line;
    }
}
```

Now, this doesn't work, it works only for the first line of `code.txt`. What is wrong?

Comment: Why are you using the buffer to read the file? That seems like a super bad idea.

Comment: I found this on the c++ reference, i don't know what to use, please advise me how @tadman

Comment: 1.txt have the same lines as code.txt, or just 1 line, or you have to put the entire file before each line of code.txt?

Comment: To copy the file in large chunks, irrespective of lines, use [`read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read). To copy it line-by-line use [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline). The buffer object should be left alone unless you are doing something really unusual.

Comment: The entire file before each line @Check

Comment: @Northumber why use rdbuf inside the loop then, I mean, read one time the 1.txt file and use it.

Comment: with the read() function as tadman suggests?  @Check

Comment: @Northumber I answer you with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your `final<<one.rdbuf();`. 
You can use this:

```
//the file to include before every string
ifstream one("1.txt");

std::string first;
if (one.is_open())
{
    // file length and reserve the memory.
    one.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    first.reserve(static_cast<unsigned int>(one.tellg()));
    one.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    first.assign((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(one)),
                 (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    one.close();
}

//final output file
ofstream final;
final.open ("final.txt", ofstream::app);

//string file
string line;
ifstream file("code.txt");

while (getline(file,line))
{
    final<<first;
   final<<line;
}
```

Maybe you want to check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8737787/3065110

Answer (score 2):

`final<<one.rdbuf()` works for only the first line because once you stream out the `rdbuf` the first time, its read pointer is sitting at the end of the `1.txt` file data.  There is no data left for it to read on subsequent streaming.  You would have to reset the `one` stream back to the beginning of its data on each loop iteration, eg:

```
while (getline(file,line))
{
   final<<one.rdbuf();
   final<<line;
   one.seekp(0); // <-- add this
}
```

Otherwise, do as @Check suggests.  Read the content of the `1.txt` file into memory one time, and then stream that out on each loop iteration, instead of re-reading the file on each iteration.