# C++ Read Entire Text File

Tags: c++, visual-c++, text-files

i try to read the entire text file using vc++ with this code

```
ifstream file (filePath, ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        size = (long)file.tellg();
        char *contents = new char [size];
        file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
        file.read (contents, size);
        file.close();
        isInCharString("eat",contents);

        delete [] contents;
    }
```

but it's not fetch all entire file ,why and how to handle this?

Note : file size is 1.87 MB and 39854 line

Comment: See the following page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to slurp a file into a std::string in c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, i found the error where,
simply the code below reads the entire file ,
the problem was in VS watcher itself it was just display certain amount of data not the full text file.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the following line

```
file.seekg (0, file.end);
```

before:

```
size = file.tellg();
file.seekg (0, file.beg);
```

As discribed in this example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/

Comment: Thanmks, but i add it and no difference still take part of the text

Comment: Do you get always the same amount? Check with file.gcount()

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is:

```
std::string s;
{
    std::ifstream file ("example.bin", std::ios::binary);
    if (file) {
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << file.rdbuf();
        s = os.str();
    }
    else {
        // error
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the C library functions fopen, fseek, ftell, fread, fclose.   The c-api can be faster in some cases at the expense of a more STL interface.

Answer (score 0):

You really should get the habit of reading documentation. [ifstream::read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) is documented to sometimes not read all the bytes, and

```
   The number of characters successfully read and stored by this function 
   can be accessed by calling member gcount.
```

So you might debug your issues by looking into `file.gcount()` and `file.rdstate()`. Also, for such big reads, using (in some explicit loop) the [istream::readsome](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/readsome/) member function might be more relevant. (I would suggest reading by e.g. chunks of 64K bytes).

<sup>PS it might be some implementation or system specific issue.</sup>