# Unexpected ifstream behavior?

Tags: c++

I am trying to load GLSL vertex/fragment shader sources into const char*  array to be used with OpenGL. The function I am using to do that is

```
const char* loadSource(const char* path)
{
   string line;
   stringstream output;
   ifstream source(path);

   if(source.is_open())
   {
       while(source.good())
       { 
           getline(source, line);
           output << line << endl;
       }
       source.close();
   }

   return output.str().c_str();
}
```

The source input works fine on first call. However if I call for the second source, the first source gets "corrupted" (both calls are inside scope of a single function):

```
const char* vs_source = loadSource("vertex.vert");  // vs_source loads fine
const char* fs_source = loadSource("fragment.frag"); // fs_source loads fine. vs_source is terminated sooner than after previous call.
```

**Note:** I tried to code vs_source directly into *.cpp file and both shaders compiled.  This points out to the fact that I must be doing something silly in the loadSource function.

**Question:** What causes such weird behaviour of the text input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you return the result from your function, you create a dangling reference:

```
return output.str().c_str();
```

At the end of the expression the temporary `std::string` obtained from the stream is destroyed and the memory returned become invalid: any access to the array result in undefined bahvior.

BTW, this approach to input is wrong:

```
while(source.good())
{ 
    getline(source, line);
    output << line << endl;
}
```

You **always** need to check that the read was successful **after** reading:

```
while (std::getline(source, line)) {
    output << line << '\n';
}
```

Also, don't use `std::endl`. If you really mean to flush the stream use `std::flush`. Finally, you can get the same effect a lot easier and probably faster:

```
out << source.rdbuf();
```

... and, of course, `out` should be declared as `std::ostringstream` (not the extra `o`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful - I really appreciate the tips as well. Btw.: What exactly is wrong with using std::endl instead of '\n'?

Comment: @vojtahavlíček: Primarily it is a common source of performance problems. See this [blog entry](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

> What causes such weird behaviour of the text input?

```
return output.str().c_str();
```

returns a pointer which points to a local variable, when function `loadSource` returns `output` goes out of scope `vs_source/fs_source` are dangling pointers. Access to `vs_source/fs_source` have undefined behavior.

To fix your issue, you could return std::string instead:

```
std::string loadSource(const char* path)
{
    //...
    return output.str();
}

std::string vs_source = loadSource("vertex.vert");  // vs_source loads fine
std::string fs_source = loadSource("fragment.frag");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why does everyone insist on doing this line-by-line reading of files? Just [load the whole file at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547645/c-read-entire-text-file). It's really simple:

```
std::string LoadFile(const std::string &filename)
{
    std::ifstream file (filename.c_str());
    if (file) {
        std::ostringstream os;
        os << file.rdbuf();
        return os.str();
    }
    else {
        // error
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Although this was suggested by @Dietmar as well, your post clarifies it nicely (wish I could upvote it :)). Btw.: Is there any advantage between checking for file.is_open() and simply file?