# Boost String Replace Doesn't Replace Newline With String

Tags: c++, string, boost

I am creating a function for my libspellcheck spell checking library that checks the spelling of a file. It's function is to read a text file and send its contents to the spell checking function. In order to have the spellchecking function process the text correctly, all newlines must be replaced with a space. I decided to use boost for this. Here is my function:

```
spelling check_spelling_file(char *filename, char *dict,  string sepChar)
{

    string line;
    string fileContents = "";
    ifstream fileCheck (filename);
    if (fileCheck.is_open())
    {
        while (fileCheck.good())
            {
                getline (fileCheck,line);
            fileContents = fileContents + line;
        }

        fileCheck.close();
    }
    else
    {
        throw 1;
    }

    boost::replace_all(fileContents, "\r\n", " ");
    boost::replace_all(fileContents, "\n", " ");

    cout << fileContents;

    spelling s;
    s = check_spelling_string(dict, fileContents, sepChar);

    return s;
}
```

After compiling the library, I created a test application, with a sample file.

Test application code:

```
#include "spellcheck.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    spelling s;
    s = check_spelling_file("test", "english.dict",  "\n");

    cout << "Misspelled words:" << endl << endl;
    cout << s.badList;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Test file:

```
This is a tst of the new featurs in this library.
I wonder, iz this spelled correcty.
```

The output is:

```
This is a tst of the new featurs in this library.I wonder, iz this spelled correcty.Misspelled words:

This
a
tst
featurs
libraryI
iz
correcty
```

As you can see, the newlines are not being replaced. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) extracts the newline character from the stream but does not include it in the returned `std::string`,  so there is no newline characters in `fileContents` to be replaced.

Also, check result of input operations immediately (see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)):

```
while (getline (fileCheck,line))
{
    fileContents += line;
}
```

---

Alternatively, to read the contents of the file into a `std::string`, see [What is the best way to read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-slurp-a-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c) and then apply the `boost::replace_all()`.

Answer (score 5):

`std::getline` doesn't read newline characters when it extracts from the stream and so they're newer written in `fileContents`.

Also, you don't need to search and replace `"\r\n"`, streams abstract this away and translate them to `'\n'`.