# C++ read the whole file in buffer

Tags: c++, raii

What is a good approach to read the whole file content in a buffer for C++?

While in plain C I could use `fopen(), fseek(), fread()` function combination and read the whole file to a buffer, is it still a good idea to use the same for C++? If yes, then how could I use RAII approach while opening, allocating memory for buffer, reading and reading file content to buffer.

Should I create some wrapper class for the buffer, which deallocates memory (allocated for buffer) in it's destructor, and the same wrapper for file handling?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

There's no need for wrapper classes for very basic functionality:

```
std::ifstream file("myfile", std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
std::streamsize size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

std::vector<char> buffer(size);
if (file.read(buffer.data(), size))
{
    /* worked! */
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't uint8_t be better than char?

Comment: read() doesn't return bool. You need to check file.bad() (or in your case file.good()).

Comment: Jamie - read() returns a reference to the ifstream itself.  By using it in a boolean context, you implicitly call operator bool(), which returns the same as !fail() => this code is correct

Comment: You can't rely on `tellg()` for the file size, AFAICR.

Comment: if the file is binary, that works. If it's text, then yes you cannot.

Comment: The constructor of ```std::Vector``` initializes all elements, which is unnecessary. I would expect this solution to be slightly less efficient than the old C equivalent with ```malloc```.

Comment: [He said you do not use `tellg()` to get the file size.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22984956/tellg-function-give-wrong-size-of-file/22986486#22986486)

Comment: @КонстантинВан good point, that's right by the language specification, but *in practice* this answer would work fine in Unix. Also works in Windows, since the answer uses the `binary` option.

Answer (score 39):

You can access the contents of a file with a input file stream [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream), then you can use [std::istreambuf_iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) to iterate over the contents of the ifstream,

```
std::string
getFileContent(const std::string& path)
{
  std::ifstream file(path);
  std::string content((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

  return content;
}
```

In this case im using the iterator to build a new string using the contents of the ifstream, the `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file)` creates an iterator to the begining of the ifstream, and `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()` is a default-constructed iterator that indicate the special state **"end-of-stream"** which you will get when the first iterator reach the end of the contents.

Answer (score 25):

Something I have in most of my programs:

```
/** Read file into string. */
inline std::string slurp (const std::string& path) {
  std::ostringstream buf; 
  std::ifstream input (path.c_str()); 
  buf << input.rdbuf(); 
  return buf.str();
}
```

Can be placed in a header.
I think I have found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/116220/257568

Comment: Great function name!

Comment: Thanks! The name comes up in Perl.