# Is there a way to get a overhead-free raw memory container from the STL

Tags: c++

`std::vector<unsigned char>` or `std::vector<char>` are the obvious candidates (depending on the context), and indeed, most example code uses them:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18816228/4442671

However, since `std::vector` must construct all objects, you end up doing an extraneous `memset()`, when compared to a simple dynamic allocation: https://godbolt.org/g/TKkwmp

It's not exactly a big deal, but it remains extra O(N) work that gets performed for no reason, so it feels like a break from the "don't pay for it if you don't need it" principle.

Writing a complete RAII wrapper around `new[]` is not hard, but I can't help but wonder:

Is there a way to get a dynamic container of contiguous uninitialized memory out of the STL, or am I stuck reinventing that wheel?

**Edit:** I'm really confused by @Someprogrammerdude's `reserve()` suggestion getting so many votes. Can someone please explain how dereferencing the reserved memory of a 0-sized vector is not a terrible idea?

Comment: Whats wrong with `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` ?

Comment: @slava it doesn't carry the size along, so I would still need a wrapper type.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "The overload (3) zeroes out elements of non-class types such as int, which is different from the behavior of new[], which leaves them uninitialized. To match the behavior of new[], a custom Allocator::construct can be provided which leaves such elements uninitialized." from here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: Create the vector as empty (default construction), then [`reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) the number of elements needed. No initialization will be made.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `reserve()` only sets the capacity, not the size I would need to `resize()`, which would then perform the construction.

Comment: Looks like this is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21028912/273767

Comment: @slava, yes, this is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: There are still `struct wrapper {char c;};` to have uninitialized struct with char....

Answer (score 2):

[`std::get_temporary_buffer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/get_temporary_buffer) does exactly that:

> Allocates uninitialized contiguous storage, which should be sufficient to store up to count adjacent objects of type T. The request is non-binding and the implementation may allocate less or more than necessary to store count adjacent objects.

You could pair it up with `std::unique_ptr` to provide a custom destructor since such buffers need to be freed with `std::return_temporary_buffer()`.

The sad thing about it is it was deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20 :(

You can ever build object in this temporary buffer with an output iterator: [`std::raw_storage_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/raw_storage_iterator):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    const std::string s[] = {"This", "is", "a", "test", "."};
    std::string* p = std::get_temporary_buffer<std::string>(5).first;

    std::copy(std::begin(s), std::end(s),
              std::raw_storage_iterator<std::string*, std::string>(p));

    for(std::string* i = p; i!=p+5; ++i) {
        std::cout << *i << '\n';
        i->~basic_string<char>();
    }
    std::return_temporary_buffer(p);
}
```