# OpenGL won´t compile GLSL Shader. Missing Extensions?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, glew

I want to compile the vertex shader:

```
#version 430

layout(location = 0)in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout(location = 1)in vec3 vertexNormal;
layout(location = 2)in vec2 vertexUV;

out Vertex{
vec2 uv;
vec4 normal;
}vertexOut;

void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(
    vertexPosition.x,
    vertexPosition.y,
    vertexPosition.z,
    1.0f);
    vertexOut.uv = vertexUV;
    vertexOut.normal = vec4(vertexNormal, 0.0f);
}
```

like this

```
pShader.ID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
std::ifstream shaderFile;
shaderFile.open(pShader.path);

if (shaderFile.fail()) {
    printf("!!!\nCannot open Shader File %s ! Shader compilation cancelled!", pShader.path.c_str());
}
else {
    std::string line;
    while (getline(shaderFile, line)) {
        pShader.content += line + '\n';
        ++pShader.lines;
    }
    const char* shaderContent = pShader.content.c_str();
    glShaderSource(pShader.ID, 1, &shaderContent, &pShader.lines);
    glCompileShader(pShader.ID);
    GLint success = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(pShader.ID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (success == GL_FALSE) {
        //errror checking
        }
```

but i am getting the compilation error

```
Vertex Shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:3: error(#132) Syntax error "layou" parse error
ERROR: errror(#273) 1 compilation errors. No code generated
```

In my fragment shader i am also getting a "/" parse error, but i can find it.

I am using glew for extension loading and glfw for input and context. 
When i run the glewinfo.exe there are some extensions marked as missing, but my AMD Radeon HD 7800 Drivers are up to date.. What is the problem and what am i supposed to do?

these are the glewinfo.exe results: http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/148318971635.txt

Comment: check what you pass into [`glShaderSource`](http://docs.gl/gl4/glShaderSource) especially your `length` parameter seems to very much not be correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you are passing a wrong length to `glShaderSource`. The last parameter has to contain the number of characters in each string. Since you could pass multiple strings at the same time, this is an array with `count` (the second parameter) elements.

The correct code in your example would be:

```
const char* code = shaderContent.c_str();
int length = shaderContent.size();
glShaderSource(pShader.ID, 1, &code, &length);
```

Additionally, reading a whole file line by line is also not very efficient.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. 
Can you quick direct me to a way to read a file faster? And what about the missing extensions? Is it common that there are missing this many?

Comment: Unless your graphic card supports them, yes this is normal.

Comment: Check this question on how to read a whole file at once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-read-an-entire-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c