# Push binary contents of file to std::string for use with Google's Snappy

Tags: c++, snappy

I'm trying to learn Google's c++ compression library Snappy. It requires that data be loaded into an std::string to compress or decompress it. How can I go about opening a file and loading the data into an std::string. Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-read-an-entire-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Unit tests of [Snappy](https://github.com/google/snappy) library. There is a [`GetContent`](https://github.com/google/snappy/blob/master/snappy-test.h#L141) function that loads binary data into the string. Also you can check how it's used for data compression there.