# UNIX API Calls: Using read() function to open and print a file to the screen adds extra random characters

Tags: c++, unix

I am trying to write a program to compare two text files using UNIX API calls. Here are the contents of my two files:

f1.txt

```
This is my sample.
It contains text
And for some reason
The last few chars
are duplicated?
```

f2.txt

```
This is another sample
Sometimes instead of
duplicating the last few chars,
it prints another new line
instead
4567865
```

I have a cpp file that opens and reads these files. My OpenRead function takes a filename as a c string, and puts the contents of the text file into a string and returns it.

```
    #include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>



using namespace std;

string OpenRead(const char*);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string text1 = "", text2 = "";

    string file1(argv[1]);
    string file2(argv[2]);


    text1 = OpenRead(file1.c_str());
    text2 = OpenRead(file2.c_str());
    cout << text1 << endl;
    cout << text2 << endl;

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);


 return 0;
}



string OpenRead(const char* filename)
{
    int inFD1;
    string text;

    char * buf = new char[fsize(filename)];

    inFD1 = open(filename, O_RDONLY, 0);
    if(inFD1 < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    else
    {
         while (read(inFD1, buf, sizeof(int)) != 0) 
            text += buf; //cout << buf;

    }   

    close(inFD1);
    delete [] buf;
    return text;
}

size_t fsize(const char *filename) {
    struct stat st; 

    if (stat(filename, &st) == 0)
        return st.st_size;

    return -1; 
}
```

The issue is that when I compile this into an executable and run my command:
fileComp f1.txt f2.txt, it opens and reads them almost perfectly fine, but produces strange output where extra characters are appended to the end. Here is what the output looks like:

```
This is my sample.
It contains text
And for some reason
The last few chars
are duplicated?
e
This is another sample
Sometimes instead of
duplicating the last few chars,
it prints another new line
instead
4567865
8
```

For some reason it appends on an e to the first file and an 8 to the second. This behavior varies among text files, but it always appends random characters from the buffer to the end.

Comment: It's C++ because `namespace` and `string` do not exist in C.  I've removed the misleading tag.

Comment: `text += buf;` expects `buf` to be a null-terminated string. `read()` doesn't add a null terminator.

Comment: @Bamar thank you. how exactly do I fix this?

Comment: Your mix of C and C++ is just awful. Either stick to C or stick to C++, but don't mix them. You are wasting memory, why do you allocate `fsize(filename)`if you are only ready `sizeof(int)` blocks of memory?

Comment: I also don't fully understsand these UNIX functions. I am trying to learn

Comment: @MiltonJames: the point Pablo was trying to make is that you are clearly writing code in C++, so you should be using C++ style file I/O instead of C style file I/O.  There is no need to use those Unix functions at all when C++ has other options available. See [What is the best way to read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue I see is that you don't check the result of read for the count of characters read.

```
    while (read(inFD1, buf, sizeof(int)) != 0)
```

You ask for `sizeof(int)` bytes on each read. But it may return less than this. So you really should have that value.

Also when adding buffer to the result `text` you assume that the buffer is already zero'd out (and thus you get a default null terminator '\0')

```
        text += buf; //cout << buf;
```

Note the `operator+=` assumes that buf is a C-String and is thus null terminated. You don't provide that guarantee with your code.

```
int len;
while ((len = read(inFD1, buf, sizeof(int))) > 0) {
    text.append(buf, len); 
}
```

Once you get it working. Take it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com for a review on best practices.

Comment: @Pablo: Thanks. That is why we have code review. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your polite and constructive criticism.

Answer (score 2):

Usual error. The problem is in your code:

```
while (read(inFD1, buf, sizeof(int)) != 0) 
    text += buf; //cout << buf;
```

This should be:

```
int count;
while ((count = read(inFD1, buf, sizeof(int))) > 0) 
    text.append(buf, count);
```

NB:

- It doesn't make sense to declare `buf` with the length of the filename, or to pass anything less than the actual length of `buf` to the `read()` function.
- You don't need to allocate `buf` dynamically. Just use `char buf[4096];` like everybody else.

Answer (score 0):

Your reading loop is broken:

```
     while (read(inFD1, buf, sizeof(int)) != 0) 
        text += buf;
```

**Cause of the problem**

First, you must verify that [`read()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/read) returns a positive number, because it could as well return a negative error message,  leaving buf in an unknown state.

Then you must get the number of bytes read (return value of `read()` ), to know where the buffer content ends, otherwise you could have remaining unitialized characters in the buffer.  If there's no null terminator at the end, you might very well get UB.

Finally, I hope that your file is not binary, because any null that would be read would be interpreted as a string terminator, causing the input to be truncated.

**Better approach**

Note also that you reserve a buffer that could contain the full file, but read only a couple of bytes each time (`sizeof(int)` bytes exactly), and then copy them into a string.  Why not use C++ streams and read content either with `getline()` for string convenience or with [`fstream::read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read), reading larger chunks of data ?

Comment: Yep just switched to binary files and now all I get is terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
Abort

Comment: Yes, it may well be that it doesn't find a null terminator and so thinks it's a huge string...  In the link behind fstream::read() you can find an example where the full file is loaded in memory with one read.

Answer (score 0):

The statement `text += buf` expects `buf` to be null terminated.  However, your loop is not placing a null character after the data it reads from the file.  At the very least, you would need to add this to your loop:

```
ssize_t len;
while ((len = read(inFD1, buf, sizeof(int))) > 0) 
{
    buf[len] = 0; // <-- add this
    text += buf;
}
```

Which BTW would break if `buf` is not allocted to at least `sizeof(int)` bytes in size, or the file data contains any null bytes in it.

You can avoid the null terminator issue by using the [`std::string::append()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append) method instead:

```
ssize_t len;
while ((len = read(inFD1, buf, sizeof(int))) > 0) 
    text.append(buf, len);
```

That being said, since you are allocating `buf` to be the full size of the file, but your loop is only reading `sizeof(int)` number of bytes per iteration, you are wasting `fsize(filename) - sizeof(int)` number of bytes when `fsize(filename) > sizeof(int)` (and your code has **undefined behavior** when `fsize(filename) < sizeof(int)`).

You should use a fixed size for `buf` instead. There is no need to allocate more than you actually read on each loop iteration:

```
string OpenRead(const char* filename)
{
    int inFD1 = open(filename, O_RDONLY, 0);
    if (inFD1 < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    string text;
    char buf[1024];
    ssize_t len;

    do {
        len = read(inFD1, buf, sizeof(buf));
        if (len == -1) {
            close(inFD1);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
        }
        if (len == 0) break;
        text.append(buf, len);
    }
    while (true);

    close(inFD1);
    return text;
}
```

Or, simply pre-allocate `text` instead, and then read the file directly into `text`.  That way, you don't need to allocating a temporary buffer at all:

```
string OpenRead(const char* filename)
{
    size_t size = fsize(filename);
    if (size < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    string text;

    if (size > 0) {
        int inFD1 = open(filename, O_RDONLY, 0);
        if (inFD1 < 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        text.resize(size);

        char *buf = &text[0];
        ssize_t len;

        do {
            len = read(inFD1, buf, size);
            if (len <= 0) {
                close(inFD1);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                break;
            }
            buf += len;
            size -= len;
        }
        while (size > 0);    

        close(inFD1);
    }

    return text;
}
```

That being said, what you are doing is the C way of reading a file.  You are writing C++ code, so you should use C++ style file I/O instead.  There are many ways to read a file into a `std::string`.  See [What is the best way to read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/).