# difference betwen file.get(char c) and file.get(char *c, int length)

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I am writting a function for my code.
the function only need a opened file to process.

here the code of the function :

```
void printFile(std::ifstream &file)
{
    file.seekg(0, file.end);
    int length = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, file.beg);

    char *buffer = new char[length];
    file.get(buffer, length);
    file.seekg(0, file.beg);
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    std::cout << "Uncreypted file" << std::endl;
    while (file.get(c))
    {   
        // loop getting single characters

        std::cout << c << " " << buffer[i] << " ";
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    delete[] buffer;
}
```

the result is weird :

> Uncrypted file 
>   t h h i i s s     i i s s     a a     t t e e s s t
>   t 
>     t ═ h ═ i ═ s ═   ═ i ═ s ═   ═ a ═   ═ l ═ i ═ g ═ n ═

after one line the buffer output something different where as `file.get.(c)` work proprely, why ?
Is this because of `the carriage return ascii letter` ?

Comment: This code broke my heart. Did you read the documentation ?

Comment: Read the documentation for `get(char *c, int length)`. It does ***not*** just read `length` characters from the input stream. It does something different. You don't need stackoverflow.com to find the documentation for get(). It should be in your C++ book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> after one line the buffer output something different

That's because you did not read the documentation for the functions that you've used.

**`file.get(buffer, length)` stops at the first newline by default** ([ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)).

So, your `buffer` only contains the first line of the file.
Your other `buffer[i]` accesses are pulling out nonsense.

Read about [how best to read a whole file into a string in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/116038/560648).

And don't program "blind", then act surprised when your program doesn't do what you wanted;
*read the documentation*!

Comment: Yes thanks for the help, i'm sorry, wanted to go too fast!

Comment: @MaximilienNowak: Hopefully this has been a valuable lesson! ;)