# What is the idiomatic C++17 standard approach to reading binary files?

Tags: c++, file, io, c++17

Normally I would just use C style file IO, but I'm trying a modern C++ approach, including using the C++17 specific features `std::byte` and `std::filesystem`.

Reading an entire file into memory, traditional method:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *readFileData(char *path)
{
    FILE *f;
    struct stat fs;
    char *buf;

    stat(path, &fs);
    buf = (char *)malloc(fs.st_size);

    f = fopen(path, "rb");
    fread(buf, fs.st_size, 1, f);
    fclose(f);

    return buf;
}
```

Reading an entire file into memory, modern approach:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::filesystem;

auto readFileData(string path)
{
    auto fileSize = file_size(path);
    auto buf = make_unique<byte[]>(fileSize);
    basic_ifstream<byte> ifs(path, ios::binary);
    ifs.read(buf.get(), fileSize);
    return buf;
}
```

Does this look about right? Can this be improved?

Comment: Pretty sure this hasn't changed since [What is the best way to read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/116038/364696); the accepted solution doesn't need to precheck the size (since not all inputs *can* be size checked, it's best to avoid it if you can); if you really like, I suppose you could switch it to `std::basic_string<byte>` to avoid the implementation-defined signedness of `char`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: He's asking to read it as a byte array, not a string. `basic_string<byte>` doesn't work, since there is no `std::char_traits<byte>` traits type.

Comment: @NicolBolas there are several answers in the linked question that are not dependent on `std::string`. In fact, some of them read the file data into another container first, so `std::string` can be removed from the equation.

Comment: I would use `auto readFileData(const std::filesystem::path&)` as interface.

Comment: I prefer traditional way, It looks simple and easy to use, what is the benefit of modern way ?

Answer (score 21):

Personally I prefer `std::vector<std::byte>`to using `std::string` unless you are reading an actual text document. The problem with `make_unique<byte[]>(fileSize);` is that you instantly lose the size of the data and have to carry it in a separate variable. It may be a tiny fraction faster than a `std::vector<std::byte>` given that it won't *zero initialize*. But I think that will probably always be overshadowed by the time taken reading off the disk.

So for a binary file I use something like this:

```
std::vector<std::byte> load_file(std::string const& filepath)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filepath, std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);

    if(!ifs)
        throw std::runtime_error(filepath + ": " + std::strerror(errno));

    auto end = ifs.tellg();
    ifs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    auto size = std::size_t(end - ifs.tellg());

    if(size == 0) // avoid undefined behavior 
        return {}; 

    std::vector<std::byte> buffer(size);

    if(!ifs.read((char*)buffer.data(), buffer.size()))
        throw std::runtime_error(filepath + ": " + std::strerror(errno));

    return buffer;
}
```

This is the fastest method I know of. It also avoids a common mistake in determining the size of the data in the file because `ifs.tellg()` is not necessarily the same as the file size after opening the file at the end and `ifs.seekg(0)` is not theoretically the correct way to locate the start of the file (even though it works in practice most places).

The error message from `std::strerror(errno)` is guaranteed to work on `POSIX` systems (that should include Microsoft but not sure).

Obviously you can use `std::filesystem::path const& filepath` in place of `std::string` if you want.

Also, especially for pre `C++17`, you can use `std::vector<unsigned char>` or `std::vector<char>` if you don't have or want to use `std::byte`.