# How to get filesize with C++ on Android using std::ifstream?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to measure a filesize in Android using `std::ifstream`. I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/5840160/5884503 and did this:

```
    std::ifstream f;
    f.open(filePath, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios::ate);
    if (f.is_open()) {
        ALOGV(TAG, "opened");
    } else {
        ALOGV(TAG, "problem opening");
    }
    auto size = f.tellg();
    f.close();
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "my tag", "filesize: %ld", size);
```

And I'm getting the filesize as `0` always, even though the file for sure exists and has more than 1mb.

I know this can be done with `std::filesystem` but this is not already or badly supported on Android. So, how to do with `std::ifstream`?

Could there be a problem with my formatting? I don't think so.

Comment: Is this answer relevant (tellg reporting incorrect values)? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22986486/783510

Comment: I don't know about Android but the file position reported by `tellg` is not guaranteed to begin at `0`. The difference between 'tellg` at the end and the beginning of the file can be used. Maybe that would work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352863/what-is-the-idiomatic-c17-standard-approach-to-reading-binary-files/51353040#51353040

Comment: >std::filesystem is not already or badly supported on Android - how does it behave?