# C++ Inserting a new line after a specific character in a text file

Tags: c++, string, file, fstream, ifstream

I am looking for a way to search for a specific character in a text file and add a new-line after every `;`

It's a pretty big document (2,7MB) if that matters.

Comment: What you are waiting for? Should someone write the complete program and put it here? This site is for Q&A related to programming and not the "do my job" ;) So please show us what you have already programmed and what is the problem you need our help for. Requesting a complete program is not what we expect here on SO!

Comment: "Inserting" a character into an existing text-file can't really be done, since you must move the text after the insertion-point, and for a file that's non-trivial. The easiest way is to rewrite the file from scratch, inserting the new characters whenever needed. Either using temporary file and file renames, or by loading it all into memory.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Would it be safe/wise to read it all into a single `std::string`? Considering it is a rather large text file?

Comment: Unless you're on a very small system with limited memory, it should be safe. I recommend you preallocate memory for the string first though, if you go that way. Otherwise I'd recommend a vector of strings, where each string is the "line" that should be written, i.e. you read the semicolon-separated strings. It will make the insertion of the newlines very trivial when you write the data back out.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: ***Would it be safe/wise to read it all into a single std::string? Considering it is a rather large text file?*** At work I read text files that are 500 to 1000 times as large into a `std::string`.

Comment: @drescherjm And what is the best way to read an entire file into an `std::string`? Does it matter (from a performance point of view) if I read it a single character at a time in a while loop?

Comment: @Ayxan see [What is the best way to read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau awesome, but wouldn't `input >> sstr.rdbuf()` miss every blank space in between words?

Comment: @Ayxan no, because [that overload of `operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) (see #11) performs **unformatted** reading. It will read the input stream as-is until it reaches the end of the stream or an error occurs. As such, the loop in the example you are looking at is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

As SomeProgrammerdude points out in the comments, inserting into an existing file isn't really feasible and one of your options is to read it all into a single `std::string` and write back into the same text file.
Here is an example implementation. We read a charter at a time and check if it is a semicolon, and add a newline after every semicolon. Notice the `reserve` part, although advised, it is not mandatory:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
  std::fstream f("test.txt", std::ios::in);

  if (!f.is_open()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open file");
  }

  std::string contents;
  contents.reserve(10000); // reserve some space for better efficiency
  char ch;
  while (f.get(ch)) {
    contents.push_back(ch);
    if (ch == ';')
      contents.push_back('\n');
  }

  f.close();
  f.open("test.txt", std::ios::out);
  if (!f.is_open()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open file");
  }
  f << contents;
  f.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
line line line line; line line line line; line line line; line line
```

Output:

```
line line line line;
 line line line line;
 line line line;
 line line
```

Note the leading spaces before lines. This is because we appended `'\n'` after every `';'`, did not replace the spaces.

Comment: You are not initializing `ch` before calling `push_back(ch)`, as you are missing an initial call to `f.get()` before entering the loop (see [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/)). You should replace `while (!f.eof())` with `while (f.get(ch))`, and get rid of the `f.get()` call inside the loop.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for the feedback! Updated the answer. Any further suggestions?

Comment: you are not checking if the second `open()` succeeds or fails. And, if you are going to use exception handling, consider using the fstream's [`exceptions()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/exceptions) method instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert new characters into the middle of an existing file, only append to the end.  You will have to create a new file, copying characters from the old file to the new file, inserting new characters as needed. For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
    if (!inFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open input file";
        return 1;
    }

    std::ofstream outFile("output.txt");
    if (!outFile.is_open())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create output file";
        return 1;
    }

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(inFile, line, ';'))
    {
        outFile << line;
        if (!inFile.eof())
            outFile << ";\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```