# read whole of each line with different column

Tags: c++, freopen

I have a text file like this:

```
1 2 3
4
5 6 7 8
just with money we can live
2 5
```

with this piece of code, I can show whole it on screen, but I cannot put it in a string, and its compile gives error :

```
string test ="";
string line2;

freopen("a.txt", "rb", stdin);
   while(getline(cin, line2)) {
       cout << line2 << endl;
       line2 >> test;
}
```

1- Is it possible to put whole of text file in "test"?
2- and instead of using something like this :

```
string test =
"1 2 3"
"4"
"5 6 7 8"
"just with money we can live"
"2 5";
```

is it possible to use a loop and freopen or something like these?

I read this "[Read file line by line using ifstream in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868936/read-file-line-by-line-using-ifstream-in-c)", but it is for identical number of column.

If there is a website to answer my question, please give it to me.

Comment: Do you want to write `test = line2;`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-read-an-entire-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c)

Comment: Part 1 of your question is a dupe of [the question suggested by uneven_mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/what-is-the-best-way-to-read-an-entire-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c); and part 2 is difficult to understand. Are you asking about string literals with multiple lines?

Comment: thanks all members and their useful answers , @Paul92 works for me

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look at this snippet:

```
string test ="";
string line2;

freopen("a.txt", "rb", stdin);
while(getline(cin, line2)) {
       cout << line2 << endl;
}
```

What happens here is that you *redirect* the text file (not totally accurate terminology) to the standard input stream (represented by the `cin` object here), and you read it line by line. Then, after reading each line, you print it to the standard output stream using the `cout` object.

What you need to do to read the file into a string is something along the lines:

```
string test ="";
string line2;

freopen("a.txt", "rb", stdin);
while(getline(cin, line2)) {
       test += line2 + "\n";
}
```

Here, you simply add lines to `test`. Note that you need to add the newlines too, since `getline` removes them.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the content of a file into an `std::string` is trivial:

```
std::string test{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{std::ifstream{"a.txt"}.rdbuf()},
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}};
```