# Refer to a std::string as a char*

Tags: c++, string, stdstring

I would like to refer (write) to a std::string like I would to a string literal (char*). This is what I'm trying to do:

```
  std::string File::readAll(){
    std::string ret;
    ret.reserve(this->size+1);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    fread((char*)ret.c_str(), size, 1, this->file);
    ret.append("\0");

    return ret;
  }
```

The string remains empty when I do this. How can I make this work?

Comment: What does that mean? How should I change my code?

Comment: Reread the docs on reserve vs resize, and consider which characters exist at which times.

Comment: The append call isn't doing what you think it does.

Comment: @1201 it's also unnecessary since std::string always implicitly has a null character at the end.

Comment: Related: [How do I read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `reserve` with `resize` and then use `.data()` (or `&ret[0]` pre C++17) instead of `.c_str()`.

Comment: Or, `&ret[0]` in earlier versions where `data()` doesn't exist (pre-C++11), or returns a `const char*` only (pre-C++17)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for the feedback. Added that in.