# Memory leak with char*?

Tags: c++, file, allocation

I read a text file with a content like this "sasdfsdf" with the following code:

```
char* o = new char[size];
c = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    fseek(pFile, i, SEEK_SET);
    b = fgetc(pFile);
    if (b == '\r') {
        o[c] = b;
        c++;
        o[c] = '\n';
    }
    else {
        o[c] = b;
    }
    c++;
}
fclose(pFile);

SetWindowTextA(TextBox1.hWnd, (n > 0) ? o : NULL);

delete[] o;
```

First I would like to know if this code is clean. I assume it is not because I am new to C/Cpp and have sometimes some problems with understanding the allocating-stuff.
I would like to use the C-style (FILE*, fopen, fseek, fgetc) to get the content of the file. The problem is that the char* o is always added something. I have an example: instead of "sasdfsdf" (text file content) it writes "sasdfsdf¨‰»3" into the edit control. I found out that the "¨‰»3" is added when the for-loop-scope is left. I assume it is something like a memory leak. I have no other idea where this characters should come from.

Comment: Why is the greeting of my post always cut off? :(
Hello folks should have been at the top of the post :)

Comment: Why not simply `while (c < size - 1 && (b = fgets(pFile)) != EOF) { ... }`?

Comment: Why do you want to use C style in a C++ program? You wouldn't have this problem if you used `std::string`.

Comment: Why not use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), which has `push_back()` and `c_str()`?

Comment: Greetings and signatures in posts are discouraged. See [Expected Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: What is the purpose of `fseek` call? The file pointer moves automatically when reading.

Comment: Related: [How do I read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/)

Answer (score 2):

As the comments indicate, you are writing in C, but have tagged your question C++. Here, C++ provides a much shorter solution that does not require any dynamic allocation on your part (and even your C style code, none is needed, simply using `constexpr size_t nelem = size; char o[nelem] = "";` would create a simple array of the desired length).

The part you are missing above is that `fgetc()` advances the *flle-position* each time is reads a character from the file stream, so there is no need for `fseek(pFile, i, SEEK_SET);` at all, it is simply superfluous.

In C++, you are much better off reading from a `fstream` rather than using C `FILE*`. You are much better off using `std::string` than `char*` as `std::string` eliminates the possibility of writing beyond he end of your array (which you fail to check for in your loop). After you read a line from your file with `getline()`, you can simply use `std::replace()` to replace all `'\r'` with `'\n'`. When you are done, all memory is freed automatically.

You would write your routine similar to:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorigthm>

void somefunc (std::fstream& stream)
{
    std::string line{}, windowtext{};
    
    while (getline (stream, line)) {
        std::replace (line.begin(), line.end(), '\r', '\n');
        windowtext += line;
    }
    
    SetWindowTextA (TextBox1.hWnd, windowtext.length() > 0 ? windowtext : nullptr);
    
    /* close file back in caller */
}
```

(note: in C++ the open file stream will be closed when the file stream object goes out of scope, so you won't need to manually close the stream)

Also Note as @RemyLebeau points out in the comments, on windows, `getline()` will remove both the CR and LF that make up the DOS line endings. If you need the manual `'\n'` to create a line-break, then you will need `windowtext += line + '\n';` instead of `std::replace` to inject the `'\n'`.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.

Comment: This code is clearly running on Windows.  There is no need for `std::replace('\r', '\n')` as `std::getline()` on Windows will handle reading both `\n` and `\r\n` line breaks for you, and not include any line breaks in the output `string` at all. If you want line breaks in the `string`, you will have to add them yourself (is `TextBox1` configured to allow multiple lines? If not, then why bother with line breaks at all?)

Comment: @RemyLebeau If I understand the question, the line breaks ARE wanted for `SetWindowTextA`. The OP is building text for a dialog that needs the line breaks. (if that's not the case -- then you are correct, there is no need for `std::replace()`)

Comment: @DavidCRankin My point was, there won't be anything for `std::replace()` to replace, because `std::getline()` won't output any `\r` characters to begin with, so you would need something more like `while (getline (stream, line)) { windowtext += line + '\n'; }`. But there is no indication in the OP's question where `TextBox1` is configured as a **single-line** or **multi-line** UI control (different settings at the OS API layer).

Comment: That makes sense, but testing with DOS CRLF on Linux, the `'\r'` is left by `getline()` and it's replacement provides the line breaks. But it would make sense on windows that both CRLF would be stripped. What's also unclear in the question if reading with `fgetc()` both `'\r'` and `'\n'` would be part of the input, so as written the OP is injecting a `"\n\n"` for every `"\r\n"`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I updated the answer to reflect the discussion.

Comment: @DavidCRankin yes, `getline()` on Linux does not handle `\r\n` only `\n`, so `\r` would be output on a DOS-style file.  However, `SetWindowTextA()` is a Windows-only function, so I'm not concerned about Linux behavior in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You must terminate the string by adding terminating null-character `'\0'`.

```
                    char* o = new char[size];
                    c = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                        fseek(pFile, i, SEEK_SET);
                        b = fgetc(pFile);
                        if (b == '\r') {
                            o[c] = b;
                            c++;
                            o[c] = '\n';
                        }
                        else {
                            o[c] = b;
                        }
                        c++;
                    }
                    o[c] = '\0'; // add this to terminate the string
                    fclose(pFile);

                    SetWindowTextA(TextBox1.hWnd, (n > 0) ? o : NULL);

                    delete[] o;
```