# How to import a file ( 3D model file ) into a buffer in c++

Tags: c++, assimp

** more specific question **
How to read a 3d file (the type of data is not known) into memory to feed the following method .

i am simply trying to import a file (a 3d model.stl file) into memory and then pass it to the following method .

```
 const aiScene* ReadFileFromMemory(
        const void* pBuffer,
        size_t pLength,
        unsigned int pFlags,
        const char* pHint = "");
```

but i don't know how to provide the following 2 arguments for the method mentioned above :

```
const void* pBuffer 
size_t pLength
```

Can someone provide me with a block of code for this ?
How can i use ifstream to read a file from memory (like "model.stl") , and then put it inside a buffer and pass it to the mentioned method

Tnx

ps .
ReadFileFromMemory requires a pointer to the data. The data can be a char[], std::string, std::vector<uint8_t> or similar. Anything that holds raw data in contiguous memory and can provide a pointer to it

How to achieve this ?

=====================
UPDATE ======================

Solution

```
    string readFile(const string& fileName)
 {
        ifstream ifs(fileName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);

        ifstream::pos_type fileSize = ifs.tellg();
        ifs.seekg(0, ios::beg);

        vector<char> bytes(fileSize);
        ifs.read(bytes.data(), fileSize);

        return string(bytes.data(), fileSize);
    }
```

and then take the buffer and it's length as the following :

```
std::string my_file = readFile("models/model_file.ext");
   const char* pbuffer = my_file.data();
    size_t  plenght =  my_file.length();
```

Comment: `size_t my_buffer_size = sizeof(pBuffer)` Are you sure?

Comment: I guess `pBuffer` should be the pointer to the array where the contents of the `.stl` file is stored.

Comment: no , i will edit the question

Comment: What is your question? Do you not know how to read a file in c++? Or you need advice on parsing the `stl` format?

Comment: question got edited

Comment: ReadFileFromMemory requires a pointer to the data. The data can be a char[], std::string, std::vector<uint8_t> or similar. Anything that holds raw data in contiguous memory and can provide a pointer to it

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/how-do-i-read-an-entire-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c). `.data()` of the string provides the pointer and `.length()` provides the length.

Comment: but for which solution , specifically ? can you post that answer here ?

Answer (score 1):

To load a file to memory, you can use this,

```cpp
std::ifstream file(file_path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);

if(!file.is_open()) { /* Bail out if the file couldn't be loaded. */ }

size_t fileSize = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0);

char* pBuffer = new char[fileSize];
file.read(pBuffer, fileSize);

file.close();

// After everything is done.
delete[] pBuffer;
```

And then you can pass the `pBuffer` and `fileSize` to `pBuffer` and `length` parameters respectively.

Assimp also provides an easy `ReadFile` function in the [`Importer`](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/class_assimp_1_1_importer.html) class which does all that for you. You just need to pass the asset file's path and the format flags to it.

Comment: thanks . if you check the assimp importer lib , it has 2 methods , ReadFile , ReadFileFromMemory . i need to use the second one , since i want to feed the importer with stream of data at the end. plus , do you think it is possible to do this /?

Comment: @PooyaSobhanipour Woops sorry my bad, and Yes, absolutely!

Comment: plus , file.read() can not accept the unsigned char * as an input . would you please check it . tnx

Answer (score 0):

as @MikeCAT said, pbuffer is pointer to the memory, where your file is stored and pLength is the size of that buffer in bytes. Check out function specs here:
http://assimp.sourceforge.net/lib_html/class_assimp_1_1_importer.html#a9b3c5e8b1042702f449e84a95b3324f6

Comment: i need to find out how to read the file into the memory in the first place . 
and the how to find the buffer size in bytes