# how to get full text from a txt file to a string variable in c++? I tried normally, but it terminate when it faces space

Tags: c++, string, file, space

I have a file named "lio.txt" with text, "my name is bio". I want to shift the full line to a string variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/how-do-i-read-an-entire-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c) By the way, it took me few seconds to search on google and find it. You should do a proper research **before** asking a question. But we can't help you any further with your specific issue since you didn't show your attempt (if any).

Answer (score 1):

this code should do it (error checking is ommited):

```
std::string read_all_file()
{
    std::ifstream file{ "file.txt", std::ios::ate }; // open the file and set the get position to the end
    std::string buff;
    buff.resize(file.tellg()); // the get position is the file size
    file.seekg(0, file.beg); // seek to the begin of the file to start reading
    file.read(buff.data(), buff.size()); // read the whole file in buff
    return buff;
}
```