# How can I use string instead of char* buffer to read the file data into string?

Tags: c++, string, winapi, char, readfile

I am using standard file-handler API to read the file , currently I have used a `char*` buffer to read the data, but I want to use `string` so I can avoid `calloc()` use. I tried to pass the string address to the `ReadFile()` function, but it's not working. Could you please help me???

```
l_FileHandle = CreateFileA(inputFilePath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
   
l_FileSize = GetFileSize(l_FileHandle, NULL);

char * l_FileBuffer = NULL;

l_FileBuffer = (char *)calloc(l_FileSize, sizeof(char));
     
ReadFile(l_FileHandle,(void *)(l_FileBuffer), l_FileSize, &lpNumberOfBytesRead, lpOverlapped);
```

Comment: This incurs a fairly costly memory allocation no matter where you want to store the data. [Memory-mapped files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/file-mapping) offer a far less expensive alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass in the address of the `string` itself, but you can pass in the address of its internal character buffer. Just make sure it has been allocated first.

```
l_FileHandle = CreateFileA(inputFilePath.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
   
l_FileSize = GetFileSize(l_FileHandle, NULL);

string l_FileBuffer(l_FileSize, '\0');
     
ReadFile(l_FileHandle, l_FileBuffer.data(), l_FileSize, &lpNumberOfBytesRead, lpOverlapped);
```

Note that the non-const version of `data()` requires C++17 or later. For C++11..14, you can use `&l_FileBuffer[0]` instead. Prior to C++11, that is not *guaranteed* to work, but *in practice* it will work in most implementations.

For a more standard way to read a file into a `string`, see [How do I read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/)

Comment: Little more help , suppose l_FileBuffer is string pointer passed to the function then how can I  replace this line -> string l_FileBuffer(l_FileSize, '\0');

Comment: Use `l_FileBuffer->resize(l_FileSize);` instead, and then use `l_FileBuffer->data()` or `&(*l_FileBuffer)[0]`

Comment: You are Awesome ..!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The proper use is `std::vector`.

```
l_FileSize = GetFileSize(l_FileHandle, NULL);
std::vector<char>  l_FileBuffer(l_FileSize);
ReadFile(l_FileHandle,l_FileBuffer.data(), l_FileSize, &lpNumberOfBytesRead, lpOverlapped);
```

Since vector by the standard ensures that the items are stored continuously.

Note that even in this way you are still implicitly allocating memory, it's just that the vector will release it automatically on destruction. If the file is known to be very small then you can afford to load it on a stack-allocated buffer instead.

Comment: Thank you Michael !! I am  curious is there any way we can use string..??

Comment: string also has a data() member but it's mostly used in storing *strings*, it's not as flexible in manipulation as vector.

Comment: `string::data` is also contiguous.

Comment: You can copy the data from a `std::vector<char>` quite easily to a `std::string`, for example  `std::string result(l_FileBuffer.begin(), l_FileBuffer.end())`.   Unfortunately, that copies rather than moves the data.