# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::detail::parse_error'

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlohmann::detail::parse_error'
  what():  [json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at line 1, column 2: syntax error while parsing object key - unexpected end of input; expected string literal
```

Trying to use JSON parsing from local `data.json` file with C++.

Code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "json.hpp"
using namespace std;
using json = nlohmann::json;
int main() {
  string text;
  int x;
  string jsonguy[5];
  ifstream i("data.json");
  i >> text;
  json data = json::parse(text);
  i.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I have the Nlohmann `json.hpp` imported locally. It continues to report these errors, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

In the statement `i >> text;`, [`operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) reads a single whitespace-delimited token from the file stream and saves it into `text`.

And then you are trying to parse that single-token `text`, not the entire file. So, if there is any whitespace present in the JSON data, you would end up passing invalid JSON to `parse()`, hence the error.

For example, if the JSON looks like this:

```json
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

The statement `i >> text` will extract only `{` and nothing else.

To fix this, get rid of the `i >> text` statement and just pass `i` itself to `parse()` instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "json.hpp"

using json = nlohmann::json;

int main() {
  std::ifstream i("data.json");
  json data = json::parse(i);
  i.close();
  // use data as needed...
  return 0;
}
```

The [`parse()` documentation](https://json.nlohmann.me/api/basic_json/parse/) says:

> ```
> // (1)
> template<typename InputType>
> static basic_json parse(InputType&& i,
>                         const parser_callback_t cb = nullptr,
>                         const bool allow_exceptions = true,
>                         const bool ignore_comments = false);
> ```
>
> Deserialize from a compatible input.
>
> `InputType`
>
> A compatible input, for instance:
>
> - **an `std::istream` object <--**
> - a `FILE` pointer
> - a C-style array of characters
> - a pointer to a null-terminated string of single byte characters
> - a `std::string`
> - an object `obj` for which `begin(obj)` and `end(obj)` produces a valid pair of iterators.

If you really want to parse the file content as a `std::string`, see [How do I read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/)

Comment: Thanks, i hadn't really checked out the documentation for nlohmann.

Comment: Even without that, what made you think `i >> text` would read the *entire* file into `text`? That is just not how `operator>>` works, for any kind of `istream`, not just `ifstream`.