# Is there a way to read the contents of a file faster in c++?

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to load a .wav file but it takes forever. The code is use:

```
    std::ifstream file (filePath, std::ios::binary);
    
    // check if the file exists
    if (! file.good())
    {
        reportError ("ERROR: File doesn't exist or otherwise can't load file\n"  + filePath);
        return false;
    }
    
    file.unsetf (std::ios::skipws);
    std::istream_iterator<uint8_t> begin (file), end;
    std::vector<uint8_t> fileData (begin, end);
```

As I said, it takes forever to load a 27MB file. But I have seen a few posts online that claim to have loaded a 106MB file in around 1400ms by using `getline()`.
I know that `ifstream::read()` can load data faster, but then I wouldn't get the data as uint8_t back.
I haven't really worked much with files so it would be nice if somebody could explain how i could read the data fast and get it as uint8_t. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I now reserve space for the bytes, but it is still slow:

```
   std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    auto size = std::filesystem::file_size(filePath);
    // check if the file exists
    if (!file.good())
    {
        reportError("ERROR: File doesn't exist or otherwise can't load file\n" + filePath);
        return false;
    }

    file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
    std::istream_iterator<uint8_t> begin(file), end;
    std::vector<uint8_t> fileData;
    fileData.reserve(size);
    fileData = std::vector<uint8_t>(begin, end);
```

Any other ideas on how I might speed this up?

EDIT 2:
I searched online and found this:

```
char* cp = new char[100000000];
    std::ofstream ofs("bff.txt"); //make a huge file to test with.   
    ofs.write(cp, 100000000);
    ofs.close();
    std::ifstream ifs("bff.txt");
    ifs.read(cp, 100000000);
    ifs.close();
```

This is extremely fast and also copies all the data into into the char array extremely quickly. Can anyone tell me how I might do this with uint8_ts?

Comment: What's wrong with `ifstream::read()`? *"I wouldn't get the data as uint8_t"* Why not?

Comment: Ok I misunderstood something. I debuged the code and the problem is copying the data into thec vector, not the reading from a file. How can I improve that?

Comment: `std::stream_iterator` is an input iterator, so the vector constructor can't tell in advance how much space to allocate. That means it has to keep resizing its data store, and that, in turn, requires copying the data multiple times. If you know the size of the file you can pre-allocate space with `fileData.reserve()`. (if someone wants to expand this into an answer, feel free...)

Comment: Related: [How do I read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/116038/364696) (and the many questions duped to it)

Comment: @FSY `.resize()` followed by one large `.read()` should be good enough.

Comment: Allocate 20-100MB buffer in RAM, then read whole file at once. Later you can scan the file in memory.

Comment: @PeteBecker I now edited the question and I now reserve space for the data, but it is still slow to actually store the data into the vector. Is there any faster method?

Comment: I suggested using `.read()` in place of `istream_iterator`. *"how I might do this with uint8_ts"* `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: `fileData = std::vector<uint8_t>(begin, end);` You call `reserve` on one vector (`fileData`) but actually read into a different one (a temporary constructed with `std::vector<uint8_t>(begin, end)`) Try `fileData.assign(begin, end);` - this would avoid the temporary. That said, `read()` directly into the vector would be the fastest.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat _reinterpret_cast?_ Certainly not! :)

Comment: @PaulSanders Apparently `basic_ifstream<uint8_t>` also works, but it's unorthodox at least.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Unorthodox?  Not sure I see why, seems to me that's what that template is for.

Comment: @PaulSanders I believe `char_traits` is not specialized for it? Maybe it's fine, I didn't check. But the sole fact that I'd have to look it up already makes me avoid it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat [Seems it isn't](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits), but given that all we're doing is calling `read` it probably doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is indeed by using `read`, but to get your `uint8_t`s without having to cast any pointers, you can use `std::basic_ifstream`, which is a template.  Using this lets you specify the pointer type.

So, quick proof-of-concept program (no error checking or anything, just to show you how it works):

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main ()
{
    std::basic_ifstream <uint8_t> f ("myfile", std::ios::binary);
    std::vector <uint8_t> v (100);
    f.read (v.data (), v.size ());
}
```

And that's it!

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aIQK6siNLzUTimGW)

Comment: Except that the standard only defines specializations of `std::basic_ifstream` for `char` and `wchar_t`, not for `uint8_t`. The correct usage is to use `std::ifstream` and typecast the pointer, eg: `std::ifstream f ("myfile", std::ios::binary); f.read (reinterpret_cast<char*>(v.data ()), v.size ());` The standard allows for an object pointer to be casted to `char*` for purposes of accessing the object's raw bytes.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I also see it that way now.