# Reading files using ifstream.read(buf, length) - receiving corrupted data (most of the time)

Tags: c++, file, stream

I'm currently learning C++ and OpenGL. Now I'm trying to read a complete file into a C style string (to be precise, the file I'm trying to read contains the source code for a GLSL shader).

Suppose the following code:

```cpp
std::streamoff get_char_count(const char *path) {
    auto file = std::ifstream(path);
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    return file.tellg();
}

char *read_all_text(const char *path) {
    auto file_size = get_char_count(path);
    auto file = std::ifstream(path);
    auto buf = new char[file_size];
    file.read(&buf[0], file_size);
    return buf;
}
```

File content:

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;

void main() {
    color = vec4(0.35, 0.35, 1, 1);
}
```

Calling `read_all_text()`, I would expect to receive the file contents exactly as described above. However, I am getting the file content, plus in most cases, some garbled appendage:

```c
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;

void main() {
    color = vec4(0.35, 0.35, 1, 1);
}
ar
```

I suspect that I'm accidentally reading into adjacent memory. However, looking at the source of `get_char_count()`, I'd expect to be given the correct count of characters in the file - I confirmed the characters in the file to be ASCII-characters only.

Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

PS: I'd prefer to stay with the `char[]` buffer approach, since it appears to be the most efficient option (as opposed to using iterators or `rdbuf`).

Comment: Related/dupe: [How do I read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/)

Comment: Not a duplicate imo, due to the problem specifically having to do with zero-termination.

Comment: not *strictly* a dupe, no. But the underlying issue is the same - to get the file contents into a string, whether that be a null-terminated C string or a C++ string, it doesn't really matter. Though, a C++ string would be better/easier in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to null-terminate the C string. The file has no `'\0'` at the end, so it is not read from the field, but a C string must be terminated with `'\0'`:

```cpp
auto buf = new char[file_size + 1];
file.read(buf, file_size);
buf[file_size] = '\0';
```