# Upload file using libcurl (transfer curl command to libcurl)

Tags: c++, curl, post, request, libcurl

How can I transfer this part of a curl command to a libcurl request? My main problem is how to correctly upload a file.

```
curl -d @path/to/data.json https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json
```

What I've tried to do is using:

```
curl_formadd(&post, &last, CURLFORM_COPYNAME, "file",
            CURLFORM_FILECONTENT, "ecg.scp", CURLFORM_END);
```

But I get a "Bad request" response.

Does anyone have an idea of how to transfer this command to libcurl code?

Comment: *how to tranfer this command to libcurl code* Use `--libcurl` with the command.

Comment: Thank you! I need to check this solution

Answer (score 1):

According to curl's [documentation](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-d), using `-d @path/to/data.json` by itself will `POST` the content of `data.json` using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. But, you can't upload a file using that format, it is only good for posting `name=value` pairs.

According to [this ReqBin page](https://reqbin.com/req/4rwevrqh/post-json-example) (Posting JSON to the Server), the URL you are posting to expects the raw JSON as-is in `application/json` format instead. And [this ReqBin page](https://reqbin.com/req/c-dwjszac0/curl-post-json-example) (Posting JSON with Curl) shows posting JSON to that URL using the following curl command, which is a bit different than the command you have shown:

> Posting JSON with Curl
>
> ```
>  curl -X POST https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json
>    -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
>    -d '{"login":"my_login","password":"my_password"}'
> ```

At the very least, that command would look more like this in your case:

```
curl -X POST https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
  -d @path/to/data.json
```

Which, in libcurl, would look something like this:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>
 
std::string json;
// read data.json into string, see:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/

CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
struct curl_slist *slist = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Content-Type: application/json"); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist); 
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, json.size());
curl_easy_perform(curl);
...
curl_slist_free_all(slist);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```