# C++ Is std::ifstream::eof() a valid delimiter for std::ifstream::fget()?

Tags: c++, filestream

`std::ifstream::get`  has as one of its signatures

```
istream& get (char* s, streamsize n, char delim);
```

Should I use `file.eof()` as  a 'delimiter' for the whole file in

```
 const std::string_view arg1{argv[1]}; // not a copy
 std::ifstream file (arg1.data() ,std::ios::in|std::ios::ate);

 if (file) {
   auto file_size = file.tellg(); // get file size
   std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[file_size]{} );
   file.seekg(0);         // go to beg of file

   file.get(buf.get(), file_size, file.eof());
   std::string_view sv{buf.get()};  // does not copy
}
```

The code *works fine* with no error, and no leaks,
but "looks suss" to use `file.eof()` in this way.

Comment: I don't think `file.eof()` necessarily fits into a `char`.

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. It must be bigger than `char`, because it has to fit all valid values for `char` and `EOF` on top of that. The valid way to read until eof is just not passing delimiter - `basic_istream& get( char_type* s, std::streamsize count );` This will read until `count` characters are read, eof happens or a failure occurs.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::ifstream::eof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof) is not a data value at all. It is a boolean status flag, used to indicate whether the stream has reached its end and there is no more data available to read.

For a data delimiter, you are thinking of [`std::ifstream::traits_type::eof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/eof) instead, which is a data value, but not a valid one that you can use as input to `std::ifstream::get()`. `traits_type::eof()` is an output value only, used to indicate when a stream has reached its end and the read operation has no valid character to return.

For what you are attempting to do, see [How do I read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/) (for example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76089931/65863) is similar to what you are attempting).

Answer (score 0):

> Is std::ifstream::eof() a valid delimiter for std::ifstream::fget()?

No, it is not a character. It is converted to character - most probably to byte `0xff` with EOF being `-1`.

Use `file.read(buf.get(), file_size)`.