# Why can’t I read one Chinese character at a time?

Tags: c++

In C++, why do I use file stream processing to read a Chinese article each time and count the number of times the Chinese character appears, but I cannot read it?

```
 istringstream iss("你是中国");
    string character;
    // Read one character at a time
    while (iss >> character) {
        // Output the character
        std::cout << character <<endl;
    }
```

**resault**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfZTq.png)

I tried changing the character set but it didn't work well

Comment: You don't try to read a _character_ here, you read a string usingformatted stream input rules

Comment: Judging from your image, the stream works as intended. What debugging information can you share?

Comment: How is your source file encoded? Which encoding is your terminal using?

Comment: Not posting as an answer, since SO doesn’t like answers that recommend a library, but you need to use ICU. ICU exists on all modern systems, is easy to hook for use, and is the _correct_ library for handling i18n. There is a lot to learn to use it properly, alas, but tuts abound on the *net.

Comment: I just read one line at a time and then process it, because the question is like this: Find a Chinese article and count the number of times each Chinese character appears.

Comment: void readFile(List* headNode)
{
 ifstream ifs("data.txt");
 if (!ifs)
 {
  cerr << "open fail" << endl;
  return;
 }

 const int chunkSize = 2;  // 每次读取的字符数，根据实际情况调整

 char buffer[chunkSize];
 string data;
 while (ifs.read(buffer, chunkSize))
 {
  // 将读取的字符添加到字符串
  data.append(buffer, chunkSize);
  // 处理中文字符
  deal(data, headNode);

  // 清空data，准备读取下一个中文字符
  data.clear();
 }

 ifs.close();
}

Comment: Are you searching for a single character you know ahead of time or are you counting how many times each character in the article appears in the article?

Comment: @Dúthomhas: "*since SO doesn’t like answers that recommend a library*" Nonsense. What is frowned upon are answers that are *just* library recommendations. Saying "go use ICU" is not an answer. Saying "here's how ICU can solve this problem" is an answer.

Comment: `ICU exists on all modern systems` I like libunistring. Much simpler.

Comment: Please post full code including `main()` and all relevant `#include`. Guessing includes is no fun.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple “count the number of times a Chinese character appears” we can rephrase it as “count the number of times a specific string appears”.

To do that, load the entire file into memory as a single string.
([Here’s an SO thread about ways to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/how-do-i-read-an-entire-file-into-a-stdstring-in-c))

Next you need to use the `substr()` function to search for the specific ‘character’ (which is itself a string).

Repeat until there are no more matches.

<sub>This presumes that the character is stored in some canonical order, meaning that multiple strings do not map to the same character in the text. If you use UTF-8 you should be fine.</sub>

Comment: 但是这样，一片文章汉字之间没有空格，怎么切割呢？？？

Comment: @user21477725 please use English

Comment: Spaces do not matter. Only the exact sequence of bytes in the string to find.

Comment: But in this case, there are no spaces between Chinese characters in an article. How to cut it? ? ?

Comment: It is not possible to use wide byte processing

Comment: @user21477725 Of course it is possible. If your source file is UTF-16LE or Guobiao, for example, finding a specific bytestring in a text is one of the most common tasks. You only need to be sure to search for the proper bytestring.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can’t I read one Chinese character at a time?

Because you are using normal characters. Any characters more than ASCII are encoded in multibyte strings or in wide strings. Proper interfaces have to be used to use them.

Research: Unicode, utf-8, utf-16, utf-32, multibyte strings and wide string in C programming language, locale and GBK encoding. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide , https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/ , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK_(character_encoding) .

The following program outputs lines `你是中国` on my ArchLinux with user defined locale `en_US.UTF-8` on a terminal KDE Konsole which supports UTF-8.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
int main() {
    std::locale::global(std::locale(""));
    // Just use wide characters everywhere.
    {
        std::wistringstream iss(L"你是中国");
        std::wstring character;
        while (iss >> character) {
            std::wcout << character << '\n';
        }
    }
    // Convert from multibyte to wide characters on the fly.
    {
        std::istringstream iss("你是中国");
        std::wbuffer_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> conv(iss.rdbuf());
        std::wistream wiss(&conv);
        //
        std::wstring character;
        while (wiss >> character) {
            std::wcout << character << '\n';
        }
    }
    // yet better - do not assume it's utf-8 and do not use codecvt_utf8
    {
        // make custom codecvt to handle that destructor thingy and use user-preferred locale
        struct mycodecvt : public std::codecvt_byname<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t> {
            mycodecvt() : codecvt_byname("") {}
            ~mycodecvt() {}
        };
        std::istringstream iss("你是中国");
        std::wbuffer_convert<mycodecvt> conv(iss.rdbuf());
        std::wistream wiss(&conv);
        //
        std::wstring str;
        while (wiss >> str) {
            std::wcout << str << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Side note: `std::wstring character;` is confusing. It's not a character, it's a string. Using `wchar_t` outputs characters on separate lines.

Also note: the whole `codecvt_utf8` and `wbuffer_convert` stuff is getting deprecated in C++, because what looks like someone with money - pointing fingers specifically at https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/443 - implemented it badly. Overall, the `wchar_t` in C has been criticized for some time now, but I subjectively like it, it's "good enough" for my most common cases. If this is a professional big project, you might anyway consider using a library like libunistring or ICU.

Comment: Note that on Windows this is slightly complicated by `wchar_t` being utf-16 so one character might be encoded in multiple `wchar_t`s

Comment: I think OP wants to read one character (one glyph) at a time. In this case, consecutive iterations of the loop should give 你, 是, 中, and 国. The question is really not that clear but the intention can be seen from OP's comments on questions and answers. He's looking for the equivalent of `iss >> ch` with `char ch;` in Unicode, which is why he named the variable `character` in the first place.

Comment: If my interpretation is correct, you did answer OP's actual question in "Using wchar_t outputs characters on separate lines", but it is easy to miss that in a casual read. Also the comment by Alan need to be addressed.