# String seems to be deallocated after return from function

Tags: c++, fstream, lifetime, ifstream

I am currently trying to make a simple function that reads a file's contents and stores it into either a `std::string` or `char` array. I have run into issues where the data is read completely fine within the function but it seems to be deleted / deallocated when the function is called.

I've isolated this problem to a small program:

Entry.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

const char* ReadFile(const std::string& path) {

    std::ifstream file;

    try {
        file.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
        file.open(path);

        if (!file.is_open()) {
            throw;
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception e) { //file does not exist
        std::string errmsg = "Unable to open file at path: " + path;

        std::cout << errmsg << std::endl;

        throw new std::exception(errmsg.c_str());
    }


    std::string contents;
    try {
        contents = std::string{ std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{file}, {} };
    }
    catch (const std::ifstream::failure& e) {

        std::cout << path << std::endl;
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;

        throw e;
    }

    std::cout << "----------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "in the function:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << contents.c_str() << std::endl;

    return contents.c_str();
}

int main() {
    const char* a = ReadFile("test.txt");

    std::cout << "----------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "in main" << std::endl;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

test.txt

```
example content

dfhfrdhdf
h

srjed
jt
tejk
e
tktre
krtk
```

console logs

```
----------------
in the function:
example content

dfhfrdhdf
h

srjed
jt
tejk
e
tktre
krtk
----------------
in main
▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌▌
```

I have tried using `strcpy` to copy the data inside of the function which gave me various memory errors (although I may have used it wrong).

Comment: Yes that's correct. Change your function to return a `std::string` not a `const char*`.

Comment: Hint: what happens to the local variable `contents` at the end of the function?

Comment: `return contents.c_str();` returns a temporary that gets destroyed when `contents` goes out of scope.

Comment: Yes, you'd either need to return the string `contents` itself (it would be copied to the main program via the stack) or declare the string outside the function and pass, by reference, as a 2nd parameter. Option 1 is definitely cleaner, 2 may be a bit more efficient (if you call the function very often)

Comment: Related: [How do I read an entire file into a std::string in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116038/)

Comment: @alle_meije Option 1 will be just as efficient as Option 2 when [Copy Elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is used on the return value.

Comment: I just thought the constructor for contents would only be called once in option 2, so (minor) difference. Not worth the loss of readability at any rate...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to the contents of a string, but unfortunately the string is destroyed when you exit the function, so your pointer is pointing at garbage.

But the answer is very simple, just change the function to return a `std::string`.

```
std::string ReadFile(const std::string& path) {
    ...
    return contents;
}

int main() {
    std::string a = ReadFile("test.txt");
    ...
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

If you really need a `char*` pointer to your string for some reason, then call `.c_str()` at the point you actually need it, not before.